# High resolution timer with C++ and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, timer

Under Windows there are some handy functions like `QueryPerformanceCounter` from `mmsystem.h` to create a high resolution timer. 
Is there something similar for Linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5524138/183120 (Cross-platform C++11 standard high resolution timer)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's been [asked before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464618/whats-the-equivalent-of-windows-queryperformancecounter-on-osx) -- but basically, there is a boost ptime function you can use, or a POSIX clock_gettime() function which can serve basically the same purpose.

Comment: Didn't know that Boost provides timer functionality. Thank you :)

Comment: Or use the [HighResTimer](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/Stable/ace/classACE__High__Res__Timer.html) from the [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library.

Comment: @lothar: +1 for pointer to ACE library, thanks.  The link you gave was stale, here's a new one: http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/Stable/libace-doc/a00227.html

Answer (score 30):

For Linux (and BSD) you want to use [clock_gettime()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock_gettime.html).

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
   timespec ts;
   // clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts); // Works on FreeBSD
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts); // Works on Linux
}
```

See: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds/275231#275231) for more information

Comment: Of course, you need to be aware of the difference between `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_REALTIME` - the former has its zero-point set to something arbitrary at system boot, and as such is only useful for relative comparisons between two `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` measurements (but is unaffected by wallclock adjustments)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a link describing how to do high-resolution timing on Linux and Windows... and no, Don't use RTSC.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160330004242/http://tdistler.com/2010/06/27/high-performance-timing-on-linux-windows

Answer (score 5):

With C++11, use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

int main()
{
    auto t1 = Clock::now();
    auto t2 = Clock::now();
    std::cout << "Delta t2-t1: " 
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
              << " nanoseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Delta t2-t1: 131 nanoseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

I have nothing but this link:
http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/rtc.txt

I'm pretty sure RTC is what you are looking for though.

**EDIT**

Other answers seem more portable than mine.

Answer (score 1):

For my money, there is no easier-to-use cross-platform timer than Qt's [QTime](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtime.html) class.