# C++ obtaining milliseconds time on Linux -- clock() doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: c++, timer, clock

On Windows, `clock()` returns the time in milliseconds, but on this Linux box I'm working on, it rounds it to the nearest 1000 so the precision is only to the "second" level and not to the milliseconds level.

I found a solution with Qt using the `QTime` class, instantiating an object and calling `start()` on it then calling `elapsed()` to get the number of milliseconds elapsed.

I got kind of lucky because I'm working with Qt to begin with, but I'd like a solution that doesn't rely on third party libraries,

Is there no standard way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Please don't recommend Boost ..

If Boost and Qt can do it, surely it's not magic, there must be something standard that they're using!

Comment: About edit - but to do it in portable way is some pain.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396014/why-is-clock-considered-bad

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use gettimeofday at the start and end of your method and then difference the two return structs.  You'll get a structure like the following:

```
struct timeval {
  time_t tv_sec;
  suseconds_t tv_usec;
}
```

EDIT: As the two comments below suggest, clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) is a much better choice if you have it available, which should be almost everywhere these days.

EDIT: Someone else commented that you can also use modern C++ with std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, but that isn't guaranteed to be monotonic. Use steady_clock instead.

Comment: terrible for serious work. Big issues twice a year, when someone does date -s, and of course NTP sync.  Use clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,)

Comment: @AndrewStone: UNIX time does not change twice per year. Or even once per year. But, yes, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is great for avoiding localised system time adjustments.

Answer (score 140):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    struct timeval start, end;

    long mtime, seconds, useconds;    

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    usleep(2000);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

    mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;

    printf("Elapsed time: %ld milliseconds\n", mtime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you add +0.5 to the difference?

Comment: @Computer Guru, it's a common technique for rounding positive values. When the value gets truncated to an integer value, anything between 0.0 and 0.4999... before the addition gets truncated to 0, and between 0.5 and 0.9999... gets truncated to 1.

Comment: This is great. I just used some make up and am using it.  Seconds = End.tv_sec - Start.tv_sec;
  Milliseconds = End.tv_usec - Start.tv_usec;
  Elapsed = (Seconds * 1000 + Milliseconds / 1000.0) + 0.5;
  printf("Elapsed seconds: %.3f \n", (float)Elapsed/1000.0);

Comment: tv_usec is not milliseconds, it's microcseconds.

Comment: terrible for serious work.  Big issues twice a year, when someone does date -s, and of course NTP sync

Comment: @AndrewStone is right, use clock_gettime(2) with CLOCK_REALTIME to compare times on the same computer.  From the gettimeofday(2) manpage: `POSIX.1-2008 marks  gettimeofday()  as  obsolete, recommending  the  use  of clock_gettime(2) instead.`  @CTT, could you update the example by changing the `struct timeval` to `struct timespec`, and `gettimeofday(&start, NULL)` to `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start)` so that people don't run into trouble?

Comment: @Bobby Powers: Warning for MacOS users: MacOS doesn't have clock_gettime().

Answer (score 60):

Please note that `clock` does *not* measure wall clock time. That means if your program takes 5 seconds, `clock` will not measure 5 seconds necessarily, but could more (your program could run multiple threads and so could consume more CPU than real time) or less. It measures an approximation of *CPU time* used. To see the difference consider this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    std::clock_t a = std::clock();
    sleep(5); // sleep 5s
    std::clock_t b = std::clock();

    std::cout << "difference: " << (b - a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs on my system

```
$ difference: 0
```

Because all we did was sleeping and not using any CPU time! However, using `gettimeofday` we get what we want (?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
    timeval a;
    timeval b;

    gettimeofday(&a, 0);
    sleep(5); // sleep 5s
    gettimeofday(&b, 0);

    std::cout << "difference: " << (b.tv_sec - a.tv_sec) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs on my system

```
$ difference: 5
```

If you need more precision but want to get *CPU time*, then you can consider using the `getrusage` function.

Comment: ⁺¹ about mention a `sleep()` — I am already thought to ask a question *(why it does works fine for everybody except me?!)* , when found your answer.

Answer (score 18):

I also recommend the tools offered by Boost. Either the mentioned Boost Timer, or hack something out of Boost.DateTime or there is new proposed library in the sandbox - [Boost.Chrono](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/chrono): This last one will be a replacement for the Timer and will feature:

- The C++0x Standard Library's time utilities, including:

  - Class template `duration`
  - Class template `time_point`
  - Clocks:

    - `system_clock`
    - `monotonic_clock`
    - `high_resolution_clock`
- Class template `timer`, with typedefs:

  - `system_timer`
  - `monotonic_timer`
  - `high_resolution_timer`
- Process clocks and timers:

  - `process_clock`, capturing real, user-CPU, and system-CPU times.
  - `process_timer`, capturing elapsed real, user-CPU, and system-CPU times.
  - `run_timer`, convenient reporting of |process_timer| results.
- The C++0x Standard Library's compile-time rational arithmetic.

[Here is the source](http://archives.free.net.ph/message/20081118.171439.bfba5fa9.de.html) of the feature list

Comment: For now you can use the Boost Timer and then gracefully migrate to Chrono when it is reviewed/accepted.

Answer (score 13):

I've written a `Timer` class based on [CTT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588307/c-obtaining-milliseconds-time-on-linux-clock-doesnt-seem-to-work-properly/588377#588377). It can be used in the following way:

```
Timer timer = Timer();
timer.start();
/* perform task */
double duration = timer.stop();
timer.printTime(duration);
```

Here is its implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

class Timer {
private:

    timeval startTime;

public:

    void start(){
        gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
    }

    double stop(){
        timeval endTime;
        long seconds, useconds;
        double duration;

        gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);

        seconds  = endTime.tv_sec  - startTime.tv_sec;
        useconds = endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec;

        duration = seconds + useconds/1000000.0;

        return duration;
    }

    static void printTime(double duration){
        printf("%5.6f seconds\n", duration);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is cool but the "nseconds" is misleading because timeval doesn't hold nanoseconds, it holds microseconds, so I would suggest people call this "useconds".

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need the code to be portable to old unices, you can use clock_gettime(), which will give you the time in *nanoseconds* (if your processor supports that resolution). It's POSIX, but from 2001.

Answer (score 4):

clock() has a often a pretty lousy resolution. If you want to measure time at the millisecond level, one alternative is to use clock_gettime(), as [explained in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538609/high-resolution-timer-with-c-and-linux)

(Remember that you need to link with -lrt on Linux).

Answer (score 4):

With C++11 and `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

int main()
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds three_milliseconds{3};

    auto t1 = Clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(three_milliseconds);
    auto t2 = Clock::now();

    std::cout << "Delta t2-t1: " 
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
              << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Delta t2-t1: 3 milliseconds
```

Link to demo: http://cpp.sh/2zdtu

Answer (score 2):

clock() doesn't return milliseconds or seconds on linux.  Usually clock() returns microseconds on a linux system.  The proper way to interpret the value returned by clock() is to divide it by CLOCKS_PER_SEC to figure out how much time has passed.

Comment: not in the box I'm working on! plus, I *am* dividing by CLOCKS_PER_SEC, but it's pointless because the resolution is only down to the second

Comment: well to be fair, the units *is* microseconds (CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000000 on all POSIX systems). Just it has seconds resolution. :-P.

Answer (score 2):

This should work...tested on a mac...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
        struct timeval tv;
        struct timezone tz;
        struct tm *tm;
        gettimeofday(&tv,&tz);
        tm=localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
        printf("StartTime: %d:%02d:%02d %d \n", tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec, tv.tv_usec);
}
```

Yeah...run it twice and subtract...

Answer (score 1):

In the POSIX standard `clock` has its return value defined in terms of the CLOCKS_PER_SEC symbol and an implementation is free to define this in any convenient fashion.  Under Linux, I have had good luck with the `times()` function.

Answer (score 1):

gettimeofday - the problem is that will can have lower values if you change you hardware clock (with NTP for example)
Boost - not available for this project
clock() - usually returns a 4 bytes integer, wich means that its a low capacity, and after some time it returns negative numbers.

I prefer to create my own class and update each 10 miliseconds, so this way is more flexible, and I can even improve it to have subscribers.

```
class MyAlarm {
static int64_t tiempo;
static bool running;
public:
static int64_t getTime() {return tiempo;};
static void callback( int sig){
    if(running){
        tiempo+=10L;
    }
}
static void run(){ running = true;}
};

int64_t MyAlarm::tiempo = 0L;
bool MyAlarm::running = false;
```

to refresh it I use setitimer:

```
int main(){
struct sigaction sa; 
struct itimerval timer; 

MyAlarm::run();
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa)); 
sa.sa_handler = &MyAlarm::callback; 

sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL); 


timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0; 
timer.it_value.tv_usec = 10000; 



timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0; 
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 10000; 


setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL); 
.....
```

Look at setitimer and the ITIMER_VIRTUAL and ITIMER_REAL.

Don't use the alarm or ualarm functions, you will have low precision when your process get a hard work.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the [Boost Timer library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/timer/timer.htm) for its simplicity, but if you don't want to use third-parrty libraries, using clock() seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

As an update,appears that on windows clock() measures wall clock time (with CLOCKS_PER_SEC precision)

```
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30(VS.71).aspx
```

while on Linux it measures cpu time across cores used by current process

```
http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/clock
```

and (it appears, and as noted by the original poster) actually with *less* precision than CLOCKS_PER_SEC, though maybe this depends on the specific version of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Hola Soy method of not using gettimeofday().
It happened to me on a running server the admin changed the timezone. The clock was updated to show the same (correct) local value.
This caused the function time() and gettimeofday()  to shift 2 hours and all timestamps in some services got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `C++` class using `timeb`.

```
#include <sys/timeb.h>
class msTimer 
{
public:
    msTimer();
    void restart();
    float elapsedMs();
private:
    timeb t_start;
};
```

Member functions:

```
msTimer::msTimer() 
{ 
    restart(); 
}

void msTimer::restart() 
{ 
    ftime(&t_start); 
}

float msTimer::elapsedMs() 
{
    timeb t_now;
    ftime(&t_now);
    return (float)(t_now.time - t_start.time) * 1000.0f +
           (float)(t_now.millitm - t_start.millitm);
}
```

Example of use:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    msTimer t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        ;
    std::cout << t.elapsedMs() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my computer is '19'.
Accuracy of the `msTimer` class is of the order of milliseconds. In the usage example above, the total time of execution taken up by the `for`-loop is tracked. This time included the operating system switching in and out the execution context of `main()` due to multitasking.