# How to get the time elapsed running a function in C++

Tags: c++, elapsedtime

I tried some codes by googling :

```
clock_t start, end;
start = clock();
//CODES GOES HERE
end = clock();
std::cout << end - start <<"\n";
std::cout << (double) (end-start)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

but the result elapsed time always was 0, even with

```
std::cout << (double) (end-start)/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000.0 );
```

Don't know why but when I get the similar in Java : getCurrentTimeMillis() it works well. I want it to show the milliseconds as maybe the computer compute so fast.

Comment: Any OS / framework restrictions? (C++ doesn't have a standard way of getting high-resolution timings...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's guaranteed that `clock` has a high enough resolution to profile your function. If you want to know how fast a function executes, you should run it maybe a few thousands times instead of once, measure the total time it takes and take the average.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/progress.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::progress_timer timer;
    // code to time goes here
}
```

This will print out the time it took to run main. You can place your code in scopes to time several parts, i.e. `{ boost::progress_timer timer; ... }`.

Comment: the compiler couldn't recognize <boost/progress.hpp> .I use Netbeans in Ubuntu

Comment: Well, you need Boost. Try `sudo apt-get install boost-dev` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This question is somehow similar to yours: [Timing a function in a C++ program that runs on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5053418/176769)

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053418/timing-a-function-in-a-c-program-that-runs-on-linux/5053607#5053607)!