# Speeding up Monte Carlo Pi

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have written a C++-program for calculating pi via the "throw random points into a quarter of a circle and count them etc.". Now my program is a bit slow in my opinion, and I have thought about some improvements to speed it up (source code is below).
My first idea is to make it multithreaded using OpenMP, i.e. split the code between (I) and (II) up into several threads so that I have for example nearly ten times more rounds without having to wait longer (on a octacore system).
Another idea I had was to use global variables and to use pointer, so that I just have to copy pointer and not tuples of integer. Drawback is (idk)?
So, what else can I do to speed the program up? I am working mainly with windows, but I can use Unix/Linux too.
Thank you very much!

Code Section:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <tuple>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>

    #define RAND_MAX 32000
    #define LOOPS 1000000

    inline std::tuple<int, int> Throw_points(void)
    {

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        i = rand() % 1000;
        j = rand() % 1000;
        return std::make_tuple(i, j);
    }

    inline bool is_in_circle(std::tuple<int, int> point)
    {
        if ((pow(std::get<0>(point), 2) + pow(std::get<1>(point), 2)) <= pow(1000, 2))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    inline double pi(void)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        long long int in_circle = 0;
        long long int out_circle = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++)
        {
            if (is_in_circle(Throw_points()))
                in_circle++;
            out_circle++;
        }
        return double(in_circle) / double(out_circle) * 4;
    }
```

Call via `pi()`

Comment: It is a slow way to compute `π`; IIRC my math courses, precision is `1/sqrt(LOOPS)` (but I could be wrong). So read some math books to compute `π` faster! And read wikipage on [approximations of π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80)

Comment: Won't help a lot, but you should cache the result of `pow(1000, 2)`, or at last replace it with `1000*1000`, which is a lot faster then `pow` and the compiler will cache the result for you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I have to use this method, otherwise I would have already switched...

Comment: Then use [openmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openmp) `#pragma`-s

Comment: Also, add a & to the function parameter of is_in_circle. You keep copying your tuples now, whereas you could pass it in by reference.
The comment by @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira about omitting pow(...) also holds for the other squaring operations: I expect that `std::get<0>(point) * std::get<0>(point)` is much faster than `pow(std::get<0>(point), 2)`.

Comment: You may want to check this entry:

https://gist.github.com/skeeto/212715

Comment: As a suggestion, change the number generator, standard `rand` function is fast but suffers from some distribution problems (cycle loop, etc) and you may end up repeating calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just played around with this a bit. Actually all of the suggestions in the comments to the original post (including my own) made virtually no difference at all.

However, getting rid of the tuple

```
inline void Throw_points(int&i, int&j)
{
    i = rand() % 1000;
    j = rand() % 1000;
}

inline bool is_in_circle(int i, int j)
{
    return i*i + j*j < 1000000;        
}
```

sped up the program by a factor of 5.

I used the boost::progress_timer solution from here, by the way: [How to get the time elapsed running a function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283031/how-to-get-the-time-elapsed-running-a-function-in-c/5283685#5283685)

Answer (score 1):

Observation on perf. Use a profiling tool; this tells you where your code is spending its time. Generally this is always surprise.

if you are in gcc land use gprof

Answer (score 0):

A few random observations:

- Squaring by multiplication is probably faster than calling `pow`. In particular, you don't want to calculate the constant `pow(1000,2)` each time.
- `int` counters might be faster than `long long` - you're already constraining the number of loops to be representable by `int`.
- Passing by reference might be faster. Or it might be slower, since the type is small. Or it might make no difference, since the function should be inlined.
- `if (X) return true; else return false;` rather than `return X;` is weird, but probably doesn't affect performance.
- `rand()` probably isn't random enough for Monte Carlo simulations; it's intended to be fast, but not high quality. Unfortunately, good pseudorandom generators are quite slow. The C++11 library has several options.

If you do make it multi-threaded, then make sure each thread has a different random seed; otherwise, they'd just duplicate each other's work. You won't be able to use `rand()` since it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Using rand is a prerequisite for this, and pi is quite good (3.145 etc.)

Comment: Yes, but I think Mike's point is that rand() isn't a high-quality PRNG.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I know that, but we only have to calculate pi up to the second number after the komma...

Comment: @arc_lupus: If it's good enough for this assignment, then fine. But it's worth bearing in mind that it's not very good when you need statistically good randomness.

Comment: Good point about `rand()`. It is sufficiently random for this specific task, but for real-life problems I wouldn't trust it at all. Aside from using `rand`, a possibly more serious problem is using the % operator to limit the range: some values will occur (slightly) more often than others.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: To get better values, I have to switch to another random seed generator?

Comment: @arc_lupus that would be the case - a so-called high-entropy one. for example, https://www.grc.com/otg/uheprng.htm

Comment: @arc_lupus: Yes. If you're using C++11, then the `<random>` library has a few options. The Mersenne Twister (`std::mt19937`) is usually a good choice.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Do you have a speed comparision between the Twister and rand()?

Comment: @arc_lupus: No, but it should be quite simple to measure them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Would it be ok to use time() (as above) as a starting seed, and for multithreading time()+"Thread-Number"?

Comment: @arc_lupus: Should be fine, if you don't run the program more than once a second; but make sure you only call `time` once, otherwise two threads might end up with the same seed if they get different time values. It might be better to use `std::random_device` (if available) to get a properly random seed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: If I use `std::random_device` do I have to worry about thread safety?