# system time in millisecond c++

Tags: c++, milliseconds, ctime, time.h

I have a queue with structs. This struct includes the exact time of pushing itself into queue

I have something like this to see system time:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

long callTime=timeinfo->tm_hour*3600+timeinfo->tm_min*60+timeinfo->tm_sec;
q.push( Call( callNum, callTime, callLength ));
```

The problem is when I pop next struct from the queue, I wanna calculate how much long struct waited in queue in milliseconds.

I hope someone can get what I wanna say.. :\

Comment: What problem are you actually having? The code that you've given compiles just fine.

Comment: you can get microseconds with gettimeofday on unixes

Comment: timer() is not a millisecond timer - its granularity is 1 second. You may want to look at the standard ctime() function, or consider operating system specific stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gettimeofday` and then subtract the time stored in your queue element. `gettimeofday()` can provide time resolution in milliseconds. You can check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588307/c-obtaining-milliseconds-time-on-linux-clock-doesnt-seem-to-work-properly) for more info.

This is assuming that every element in the stack also stores the time that it was pushed in. If the element doesn't have it, you can either store a structure with the element and the time or have a separate stack with the times alone.

Comment: C:\vy2\main.cpp|37|error: 'timeval' was not declared in this scope| btw. #include <ctime> is already typed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function `gettimeofday()` rather than `time()`. The former supports sub-millisecond precision, while the latter is only accurate to the nearest second.

Comment: Not part of standard C++, so his platform may or may not have it.

Comment: @WhoCares No, it doesn't - it's a POSIX thing not supported by windows.

Comment: I just need to add milisecond to this line: long callTime=timeinfo->tm_hour*3600+timeinfo->tm_min*60+timeinfo->tm_sec I mean something like tm_msec :\

Comment: @WhoCares We know what you want, and we are telling you there is no portable way to do it!

Comment: I think it can be with clocks_per_sec but i just cant calculate it in my mind. im totally collapsed. somebody help pls:)

Answer (score 0):

gettimeofday is a answer, but if you want just check how long your item was in queue clock_gettime() could be more suitable.
For example, you could use CLOCK_MONOTONIC (suppose we do not count sec):

```
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
// do some action ....
struct timespec ts2;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts2);
std::cout << "spend " << ts2.tv_nsec - ts.tv_nsec << " nanoseconds" << std::endl;
```

And, of course, clock_gettime is not part of C++, it is part of POSIX.1-2008

Comment: thnks for reply but it must run under unix. is that useful for this?

Comment: For sure, it is defined in Single UNIX Specification, Version 2.