# Performance hit in CUDA program that calls kernel repeatedly within a for loop

Tags: for-loop, cuda, gpu, dynamic-programming

I have a CUDA program that calls the kernel repeatedly within a for loop. The
code computes all rows of a matrix by using the values computed in the previous one
until the entire matrix is done. This is basically a dynamic programming algorithm.
The code below fills the (i,j) entry of many separate matrices in parallel with
the kernel.

```
for(i = 1; i <=xdim; i++){

  for(j = 1; j <= ydim; j++){ 

    start3time = clock();
    assign5<<<BLOCKS, THREADS>>>(Z, i, j, x, y, z)
    end3time = clock(); 
    diff = static_cast<double>(end3time-start3time)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000); 
    printf("Time for i=%d j=%d is %f\n", i, j, diff); 
  }

}
```

The kernel assign5 is straightforward

```
__global__ void assign5(float* Z, int i, int j, int x, int y, int z) {

  int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  char ch = database[j + id];

  Z[i+id] = (Z[x+id] + Z[y+id] + Z[z+id])*dev_matrix[i][index[ch - 'A']];

  }

}
```

My problem is that when I run this program the time for each i and j is 0 most of the
time but sometimes it is 10 milliseconds. So the output looks like

```
Time for i=0 j=0 is 0
Time for i=0 j=1 is 0
.
.
Time for i=15 j=21 is 10
Time for i=15 j=22 is 0
.
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I don't see a thread race condition. If I add

```
if(i % 20 == 0) cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

right after the first loop then the Time for i and j is mostly 0. But then the time 
for sync is sometimes 10 or even 20. It seems like CUDA is performing many operations
at low cost and then charges a lot for later ones. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely that is just aliasing because the precision of the time source is too low?

Comment: I forgot to add that the variables Z and database are device global  arrays and dev_matrix and index and device constant arrays. The memory access is coalesced.

Comment: The results are inconsistent because your clock resolution is about 10ms, like talonmies said. Better to just measure the time of the whole loop. If you need high-res, per-iteration measurements, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588377/324625) should help.

Comment: I've measured the time now in microseconds using the timer indicated above. Each early iteration (all i < 20) takes 3 or 4 microseconds. It then spikes to about 120 for the next three iterations and 8 or 9 microseconds from then on. In between there are more spikes but most iterations take 8 or 9. Interestingly, if I add a cudaThreadSynchronize() right after the first loop then all iterations take 3 or 4 microseconds without spikes. The cudaThreadSynchronize() takes about 700 microseconds each time. I  don't see a race condition in my program. Could you say why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Is this on a WDDM windows platform with a recent driver? If so, the driver does batching to amortise the higher latency of that platform.

Comment: No it's on Linux. I believe I may be measuring the runtime incorrectly. Someone on a different forum said I should be using cudaEventRecord and cudaEventSynchronize. I'm getting consistent results now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a misconception about what a kernel call in CUDA actually does on the host. A kernel call is non-blocking and is only added to the device's queue. If you're measuring time before and after your kernel call, then the difference has nothing to do with how long your kernel call takes (it would measure the time it takes to add the kernel call to the queue).

You should add a cudaThreadSynchronize() after **every** kernel call and before you measure end3time. cudaThreadSynchronize() blocks and returns if all kernels in the queue have finished their work.

This is why

```
if(i % 20 == 0) cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

made spikes in your measurments.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. Also, it appears that cudaMemcpy will block until all threads are finished.

Comment: Yes, calls to cudaMemcpy block on the host until all threads are finished. This is the standard memcopy function because thats what you want most of the time. There is also cudaMemcpyAsync(), which is the non-blocking variant.

Comment: Just as reference for future readers: cudaThreadSyncronize is deprecated and cudaDeviceSynchronize should be used instead.