# How to invoke a function very accurately in milli seconds gaps (e.g, every 20ms) using C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I know following methods like sleep, conditional wait with time-outs can be used to delay a particular thread. How accurate is the conditional wait over sleep in Linux?

If there any OS provided mechanism to to get timing in milli seconds of range?

Thanks,
Prasanth

Comment: `select()` with a timeout can be used to implement a timer.

Comment: Regarding timing accuracy / granularity, I think you're at the mercy of the scheduler 'tick' interval and (unlike Windows) I don't know of any way to change it.  A little info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472211/5743288.  There is, however, a low latency Linux kernel kicking around somewhere.  That might offer possibilities.

Comment: What are the actual requirements on the delay between two calls? BTW: You're asking two questions (bad!) and the first can be answered when you find a solution to the second.

Comment: Look up "realtime linux".   Formally, the entire linux OS (kernel and user mode programs) are executed by a realtime microkernel, so anything designated as realtime can preempt (run with higher priority than) everything running in the linux OS.   RT linux is a set of extensions that allow running tasks directly in that microkernel (but does require enforcing timing constraints to stop problems such as those tasks starving the entire linux OS).   Not every linux distributuon comes with the RT linux extensions though.