# HTimer in Linux (High resolution timer)

Tags: linux, timer

Does somebody has any idea of HT Timer in Linux?
I will be glad if someone shares some code snippets with examples of how to implement the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would you like to achieve with a timer?

Comment: I have an application and it needs a timer to track it's execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your application type.

For event-driven applications your event notification library (like [libevent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent)) should provide timer scheduling functionality.

There is also POSIX [timer_create()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/timer_create.html) function, that can deliver timer expiry as a signal or a callback in another thread. Latest Linux provides [timerfd](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) mechanism to deliver timer expirations through a regular file descriptor that can be registered with `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538609/high-resolution-timer-with-c-and-linux) similar question with sample code for [clock_gettime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock_gettime.html).

Comment: I want fo HRTTimer code samples please (High resolution timers)

Comment: See code sample [here](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/). I believe it should fit your purposes well.