# Time taken to execute a function shows 1.#INF00

Tags: c, clock, performance-testing

I have to measure the performance of a decoder in terms of number of frames decoded per second. i.e. calculating the FPS.

Below is what my code snippet looks like:

```
//global variables
clock_t start,stop;
double totTime, FPS;


main()
{
   while(End_of_file)
   {
      start=clock();

      //Decode function is called here

      stop=clock();

      totTime=stop-start;

      FPS=1/(totTime/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

      printf("\n %lf fps\n",FPS);
   }
}
```

The printf statement sometimes prints proper value, however sometimes it gives a value `1.#INF00` which according to whatever i have searched is a floating point exception also called as `positive infinity`, which occurs when we try to divide a positive number by zero. So my question is why is it taking `totTime=start-stop;` being considered as 0 ? Second, if not clock(), then how do i get the time taken by the decode function.

Any suggestions regarding the same will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your 'normal' times (*not* FPS) very close to zero? Computers are fast, and the resolution of `clock` is rather low (1 millisecond on my system). In addition, there is bound to be lots of jittering (disk access, mouse movement, etc.). Try running your decode routine 1,000 or even more times.

Comment: @Jongware: Thanks for your comment. So if its close to zero, then is there any other mechanism to check time taken to execute a function?

Comment: That would be the "Try running your decode routine 1,000 or even more times" part.

Comment: But i need to calculate the time taken to run decode for each frame in the video.

Comment: Okay, so you are not looking for "profiling" but rather a "real-time" solution. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749621/high-resolution-timer-in-linux

Comment: clock_gettime() function is for linux. I'm working on windows. Any other way to measure execution time?

Comment: There is a Windows API for that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404277/porting-clock-gettime-to-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper macro for this is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, not `CLOCK_PER_SEC`.

Also, instead of using `clock()`, you can use `clock_gettime()` since you just want the time.

Comment: Sorry thats a typing mistake. Otherwise i would have got a compilation error.

Comment: Sorry working on windows platform. clock_gettime() is in linux.

Comment: Is your code taking a lot of time ? I mean, if you add printfs before and after the code, can you see them slowly or very fast ?

Comment: I think you should then try calculating the time taken by the whole while loop instead of calculating the time for each iteration. You won't be able to get more precise times, even by doing some complex math.