# clock_gettime() doesn't work

Tags: linux, time.h

I read the following manual: 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

and I wrote the following code:

```
#include <time.h>
int main() { 
    struct timespec clk;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &clk);
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, I get the following errors:

> Symbol CLOCK_REALTIME could not be resolved
>
> undefined reference to clock_gettime

I still don't understand what is the problem. I included the  header, and these names show in this header.

Comment: Works for me... What Linux distro and version are you using? Are you sure all packages for C development are correctly installed? What's the command line you use for compiling the program?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04.
How can I check if all packages for C development are installed? 
The command lines is: gcc -o "example" ./main.o
and I'm doing it by eclipse.

Comment: could you try, from the commandline `gcc -o somename main.c` ? I don't know enough about ubuntu to help you with the packages that must be present, sorry.

Comment: In which time.h did you look? I could only extract the source archive of package libc6-dev at the moment. CLOCK_REALTIME is not defined in /usr/include/time.h there.

Comment: This will install the required packages : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install g++` .  I.e. the dependencies libc6-dev, linux-libc-dev, ( libgcc-4.x-dev, ).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should use`#define _POSIX_TIMERS`,`#define _REENTRANT`
besides, when you compile the code, make sure to link the real-time library which is `cc filename.c -o filename -lrt`

Update 1.0:
sometimes in windows or mac os, C ide may not include real-time library automatically, or we may not used the posix directly without _POSIX_TIMES, therefore you have to link the real-time library manually. In Linux, you can just type in `cc filename.c -o filename -lrt` to compile the c file.