# How to get today's UTC Midnight time in Milliseconds in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

For Windows C++, I am trying something like -

```
unsigned long long int Device::getCurrentUtcTimeinMiliSecond() {
    time_t ltime;
    time(&ltime);
    std::tm* newtime = gmtime(&ltime);
    newtime->tm_hour = 0;
    newtime->tm_min = 0;
    newtime->tm_sec = 0;
    time_t timex = mktime(newtime);
    // Want to convert tm* to total miliseconds since Midnight 1970
    return  (long long)timex * 1000;
}
```

Is there any other way or am I going in right direction? If yes, then how to convert `tm*` to total time millisecond since 1970 Midnight?

Or someone can suggest simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Are you using C++11 ?

Comment: You might be looking for [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime)

Comment: I am using C++ 11. @Eric.

Comment: I have changed the code to use `mktime`. But not sure if it is correct or not. I will update my code above.

Comment: The solution provided by them in the other question doesn't match the right value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use clock_gettime;  This is not available by default under windows, but there is an an example [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404277/porting-clock-gettime-to-windows)

Once you have clock_gettime, you can do the following:

```
#define MS_PER_SEC 1000
#define NS_PER_MS  1000000
timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
unsigned long long msecs = (((unsigned long long) ts.tv_sec) * MS_PER_SEC + (ts.tv_nsec / NS_PER_MS);
return msecs;
```

You could clean that up a bit, but once you have clock_gettime() it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Did we read the same question?

Comment: OP asked for *midnight*.