# Is clock_gettime() correctly implemented in MinGW GCC 8.2.0?

Tags: c, mingw, iso, c11

By chance, I found out about the existence of the `clock_gettime()` function for Linux systems. Since I'm looking for a way to measure execution time of a function, I tried it in the MinGW gcc 8.2.0 version on a Windows 10 64-bit machine:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct timespec tstart, tend;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &tstart);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &tend);
    printf("It takes %li nanoseconds for 100,000 empty iterations.\n", tend.tv_nsec - tstart.tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}
```

This code snippet compiles without warnings/errors, and there are no runtime failures (at least not written to stdout).

Output:

```
It takes 0 nanoseconds for 100,000 empty iterations.
```

Which I don't believe is true.

Can you spot the flaw?

---

One more thing:

According to the [N1570 Committee draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (April 12, 2011) of the ISO/IEC 9899:201x, shouldn't `timespec_get()` take the role of `clock_gettime()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That loop should get optimized out to nothing at all, so with a low resolution clock (resolution is not necessarily individual nanoseconds; it may advance in much larger units which `clock_getres` should be able to tell you) 0 is a plausible result. But you have a few other bugs in your code like mixing `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` and not checking the return value of `clock_gettime` (it might be telling you these clocks aren't supported).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code is querying two different clocks (`CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` for `tstart` and `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` for `tend`), so it makes no sense to compare the two values. Secondly, you're only looking at the `tv_nsec` field of the `struct timespec` returned by `clock_gettime()`, and your difference might be wrong even if querying the same clock both times. Also, your compiler could be optimizing the empty `for` loop away, but that's impossible to say without looking at the generated binary, however I would find that unlikely unless you were compiling with `-O1` or `-O2` (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bFLKBE) for example, the loop is eliminated only with `-O2`).

Furthermore, Windows is not POSIX compliant at all, and MinGW can only emulate the behavior of `clock_gettime()` to some extent, so I wouldn't really trust it to return precise values. It seems to be okay for mingw-w64 [looking at the source code](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/dcd990ed423381cf35702df9495d44f1979ebe50/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads/src/clock.c#L139), but I don't know if that's the version you're using. Even though  a `struct timespec` object  describes  times  with  nanosecond  resolution,  the  available resolution is system dependent and may even be greater than 1 second. You might want to check what `clock_getres()` says.

> According to the [N1570 Committee draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (April 12, 2011) of the ISO/IEC 9899:201x, shouldn't `timespec_get()` take the role of `clock_gettime()` instead?

The C standard does not say *anything* about which function should take the role of which other. The `timespec_get()` function definitely does *not* have the same semantics as `clock_gettime()`. The `timespec_get()` function only works on "calendar time" (which should be the same as `CLOCK_REALTIME` when using `clock_gettime()`).

Comment: `timespec_get` is comparable to `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_REALTIME`, but doesn't support the clocks OP wants to use.