# Why is clock_gettime() not working with MinGW, even though I have time.h

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

The linker keeps telling me that clock_gettime() is undefined.

I have tried using -lrt but then gcc says that it can't find that either.

Am I missing some extra library I needed to download?

```
// test.c

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec x;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &x);
    printf("%d\n", x.tv_sec);
    return 1;
}
```

When I try to compile this using GCC with MinGW, it puts out this:

```
gcc test.c
undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
```

or

```
gcc test.c -lrt
cannot find -lrt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: See e.g. [Is clock_gettime() correctly implemented in MinGW GCC 8.2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020968/is-clock-gettime-correctly-implemented-in-mingw-gcc-8-2-0)

Comment: The function seems to be implemented in Mingw's libpthread library so try `-pthread`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about the version of MinGW you are using. I cannot reproduce the problem on `MINGW64_NT-10.0-19042 HOSTNAME 3.3.6-341.x86_64 2022-09-05 20:28 UTC x86_64 Msys`. I can compile the program with `gcc test.c -o test` and run it without any problem.

Comment: @IanAbbott, including pthread worked. thanks for your help :)