# Error while porting POSIX function clock_gettime() to windows specifically for Apache AGE

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile and create a dynamic linking library for [Apache-Age](https://github.com/apache/age).
There's a use of clock_gettime() in `src/backend/utils/adt/agetype.c` to get the timestamp of query.

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    clock_gettime(st, &ts);
    ms += (ts.tv_sec * 1000) + (ts.tv_nsec / 1000000);
```

I followed [this stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404277/porting-clock-gettime-to-windows) but in all the answers clock_gettime() is accepting `CLOCK_REALTIME` as a parameter which is also not available in MSVC.

But in AGE implementation st variable of type `SYSTEMTIME` struct is used defined in `minwinbase.h`

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
    WORD wYear;
    WORD wMonth;
    WORD wDayOfWeek;
    WORD wDay;
    WORD wHour;
    WORD wMinute;
    WORD wSecond;
    WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME, *LPSYSTEMTIME;
```

How can I make my own clock_gettime() with `SYSTEMTIME` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLOCK_GETTIME` & `CLOCK_REALTIME` are POSIX only. Instead of defining your own `clock_gettime()` for Windows you can use `timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);` from `time.h`.

So, in `src/backend/utils/adt/agetype.c`:

```
#include <time.h>
.
.
.
Datum age_timestamp(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    agtype_value agtv_result;
    struct timespec ts;
    long ms = 0;

    /* get the system time and convert it to milliseconds */
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    ms += (ts.tv_sec * 1000) + (ts.tv_nsec / 1000000);
    
    /* build the result */
    agtv_result.type = AGTV_INTEGER;
    agtv_result.val.int_value = ms;

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(agtype_value_to_agtype(&agtv_result));
}
```