# Timing functions in C

Tags: c, profiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [C++ Timer function to provide time in nano seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds)
> [High resolution timer with C++ and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538609/high-resolution-timer-with-c-and-linux)

I would like to time a few C functions, and I'm trying to come up with a systematic way of doing so. So far, what I have is the simplest form of timing:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval start_time, end_time;
gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
<my function>
gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
total_usecs = (end_time.tv_sec-start_time.tv_sec) * 1000000 + 
    (end_time.tv_usec-start_time.tv_usec);
printf ("parfib,%ld,%d\n",(long)res,total_usecs);
```

I have also found

```
timespec time1, time2;
int temp;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
     <my function>
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
cout<<diff(time1,time2).tv_sec<<":"<<diff(time1,time2).tv_nsec<<endl;
```

But even with `std=gnu99` I have not been able to get this to work (I copied the above code from a website, but I did translated into C before compiling :). Regardless, I'm wondering if any of you know of docs or blogs or something that discusses timing functions like I'm trying to do. Note, I'm not after profilers such as `gprof` or the like, I need this profiler to be hand-made.

Comment: I guess you need better sampling than the time function?

Comment: "I need this profiler to be hand-made". If the goal is to *measure*, just wrap a loop around <my function> to get all the accuracy you want. If the goal is to effectively *locate speedup opportunities*, measuring ain't gonna do it. *[This does it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile the second example you will need:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L timer.c -lrt
```

[`_POSIX_C_SOURCE`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html) specifies which POSIX version you're targeting - it needs to be defined before any system header files get included, so doing it via `-D` is safest. `clock_gettime` also depends upon linking to librt (`-lrt`).