# Seeking C++ implementation of `hires_time_in_seconds()`

Tags: c++, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [High resolution timer with C++ and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538609/high-resolution-timer-with-c-and-linux)

`double hires_time_in_seconds();`

I'm looking for this function for Windows, Linux too if you have it.
It is mentioned in http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/.
I've looked on the web.
I know it's not a standard function but if anybody has an implementation that they want to share, that would be great.

Failing that, I need something as fine grained as possible to do synchronization in a client server game.

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/libs/date_time/)..? It provides microsecond or nanosecond resolution, depending on how you build. (Also, how is a timer with seconds-level granularity "hires"?)

Comment: You should refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds.

Comment: C++ has `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` now. It hasn't been implemented in VS as of VS2010, but GCC on linux should have it.

Comment: @bames53 : Good point, and for older platforms there is now [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/libs/chrono/).

Comment: Rather than Boost I'll probably use the Windows and Unix specific versions mentioned in the duplicates. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a real function, it's just a self-descriptive placeholder name used in that blog post's example code.

For Windows, you'll want to use [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) along with [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  For Unix-based OSes, you'll want to use [`gettimeofday(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday).