# C how to measure time correctly?

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, time, measurement

This is the "algorithm", but when I want to measure the execution time it gives me zero. Why?

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000
...

clock_t start, end;

start = clock();

for( i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
{
non_parallel[i] = vec[i] * vec[i];
}
end = clock();
printf( "Number of seconds: %f\n", (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
```

So What should i do to measure the time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things:

1. `10000` is not a lot on a modern computer. Therefore that loop will run in probably less than a millisecond - less than the precision of `clock()`. Therefore it will return zero.
2. If you aren't using the result of `non_parallel` its possible that the entire loop will be optimized out by the compiler.

Most likely, you just need a more expensive loop. Try increasing `ARRAY_SIZE` to something much larger.

---

**Here's a test on my machine with a larger array size:**

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100000000

int main(){

    clock_t start, end;

    double *non_parallel = (double*)malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(double));
    double *vec          = (double*)malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(double));

    start = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        non_parallel[i] = vec[i] * vec[i];
    }

    end = clock();
    printf( "Number of seconds: %f\n", (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC );


    free(non_parallel);
    free(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Number of seconds: 0.446000
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an unreliable way to actually time number of seconds, since the `clock()` function is pretty low precision, and your loop isn't doing a lot of work. You can either make your loop do more so that it runs longer, or use a better timing method.

The higher precision methods are platform specific. For Windows, see [How to use QueryPerformanceCounter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) and for linux see [High resolution timer with C++ and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538609/high-resolution-timer-with-c-and-linux)

Comment: Um no, the OP is already casting one of the operands to `double`.

Comment: @Mysticial Fail on my part, fixed my answer.