# C++ time() function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, time, timer

I call the time() function, run a sorting algorithm on a vector, then call time() function again.  When I do this, the value returned from time() is the exact same for both calls, so I cannot calculate how long it takes for the sorting to complete.  This happens when the vector has any number of elements; it doesn't change.  I call time(NULL) in the sort() function at the bottom.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int listSize, listType;
static const char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

template <typename E>
void printVector(vector<E>& list)
{
    typename vector<E>::iterator it;
    for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
}

template <typename E>
vector<E> generateList(int listType, int listSize)
{   
    vector<E> list;
    if (listType == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            int random = rand() % 10001;
            list.push_back(random);
        }
    } 
    else if (listType == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            double random = (10000 * (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
            list.push_back(random);
        }
    }
    else if (listType == 3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            char random = alphabet[rand() % (sizeof(alphabet) - 1)];
            list.push_back(random);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid type\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    return list;
}

template <typename E>
void insertionSort(vector<E>& list)
{
    E i, j, tmp;

    for (i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        j = i;
        tmp = list[i];
        while (j > 0 && tmp < list[j-1])
        {
            list[j] = list[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        list[j] = tmp;
    }
}

template <typename E>
vector<E> merge(vector<E>& list, vector<E>& left, vector<E>& right)
{
    vector<E> result;
    unsigned left_it = 0, right_it = 0;

    while(left_it < left.size() && right_it < right.size())
    {
        if(left[left_it] < right[right_it])
        {
            result.push_back(left[left_it]);
            left_it++;
        }
        else
        {
            result.push_back(right[right_it]);
            right_it++;
        }
    }

    while(left_it < left.size())
    {
        result.push_back(left[left_it]);
        left_it++;
    }

    while(right_it < right.size())
    {
        result.push_back(right[right_it]);
        right_it++;
    }
    list = result;              
    return list;
}

template <typename E>
vector<E> mergeSort(vector<E>& list)
{
    if(list.size() == 1)
    {
        return list;
    }

    typename vector<E>::iterator middle = list.begin() + (list.size() / 2);

    vector<E> left(list.begin(), middle);
    vector<E> right(middle, list.end());

    left = mergeSort(left);
    right = mergeSort(right);

    return merge<E>(list, left, right);
}

template <typename E>
void shiftRight(vector<E>& list, int low, int high)
{
    int root = low;
    while ((root*2)+1 <= high)
    {
        int leftChild = (root * 2) + 1;
        int rightChild = leftChild + 1;
        int swapIndex = root;
        if (list[swapIndex] < list[leftChild])
        {
            swapIndex = leftChild;
        }
        if ((rightChild <= high) && (list[swapIndex] < list[rightChild]))
        {
            swapIndex = rightChild;
        }
        if (swapIndex != root)
        {
            double tmp = list[root];
            list[root] = list[swapIndex];
            list[swapIndex] = tmp;
            root = swapIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

template <typename E>
void heapify(vector<E>& list, int low, int high)
{
    int midIndex = (high - low - 1)/2;
    while (midIndex >= 0)
    {
        shiftRight(list, midIndex, high);
        midIndex--;
    }
    return;
}

template <typename E>
void heapSort(vector<E>& list, int size)
{
    heapify(list, 0, size - 1);
    int high = size - 1;
    while (high > 0)
    {
        double tmp = list[high];
        list[high] = list[0];
        list[0] = tmp;
        high--;
        shiftRight(list, 0, high);
    }
    return;
}

template <typename E>
int pivot(vector<E>& list, int first, int last) 
{
    int p = first;
    E pivotElement = list[first];

    for(int i = first+1 ; i <= last ; i++)
    {
        if(list[i] <= pivotElement)
        {
            p++;
            E temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[p];
            list[p] = temp;
        }
    }

    E temp = list[p];
    list[p] = list[first];
    list[first] = temp;

    return p;
}

template <typename E>
void quickSort(vector<E>& list, int first, int last) 
{
    E pivotElement;

    if(first < last)
    {
        pivotElement = pivot(list, first, last);
        quickSort(list, first, pivotElement-1);
        quickSort(list, pivotElement+1, last);
    }
}
template <typename E>
bool sort(vector<E>& list)
{
    int again = 0;
    int sort = 0;
    long int start, finish, duration;

    cout << "Which sorting algorithm would you like to use?" << endl;
    cout << " 1 for Insertion Sort\n 2 for Merge Sort\n 3 for Heapsort\n 4 for Quicksort" << endl;
    cin >> sort;
    cout << endl;

    printVector(list);    
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    start = time(NULL);
    if (sort == 1)
        insertionSort(list);
    else if (sort == 2)
        mergeSort(list);
    else if (sort == 3)
        heapSort(list, list.size());
    else if (sort == 4)
        quickSort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
    else {
        cout << "Invalid command\n";
        exit(0);
    }    
    finish = time(NULL);

    duration = finish - start;

    cout << start << endl;
    cout << "Sorting the list took " << duration << " seconds." << endl;  
    cout << finish << endl;

    printVector(list);

    while (again == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nWould you like to go again? (1 for yes, 2 for no)\n";
        cin >> again;
        if (again == 1)
            return true;
        else if (again == 2)
            return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    bool again = true;
    while (again) {
        cout << "How many items do you want to sort? (0 to quit)" << endl;
        cin >> listSize;
        if (listSize == 0)
            exit(0);
        else if (listSize < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid input.\n";
            exit(0);
        }
        /* Change first parameter of generateList() to 1-3
         * 1 for ints, 2 for doubles, 3 for chars
         * 
         * Also change vector types in the three places below to
         * the corresponding parameter type.
         */
        vector<char> list = generateList<char>(3, listSize);
        again = sort<char>(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`time()` only has second resolution. Your sort probably finishes fast enough for you to not see it tick.  If you want to time it, you'll need to use a clock with more precision.

If you have access to C++11, the easiest would be:

```
auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// do sort() stuff here
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

auto elapsed_usec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();;
```

Pre-C++11, you can use this:

```
struct timeval begin, end;
gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
// do sort() stuff here
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

long elapsed_usec = (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) * 1e6 + 
                    (end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec);
```

Comment: How do I gain access to C++11?

Comment: @AlishasPayPal If you're using gcc or clang of a late enough version, you can add the `-std=c++11` flag and then `#include <chrono>`.

Comment: where does .count() come from?

Comment: @AlishasPayPal [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count)'s a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you calculate the time by making a difference between `finish` and `start` time:

- `time_t` is generally expressed in seconds.
- And *portable programs should not use the value returned by [`time()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) directly, but always rely on calls to other elements of the standard library to translate them to portable types (such as localtime, gmtime or difftime).*
- With [`difftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/?kw=difftime) you'd get a double value expressed in seconds, but using the precision available to the specific library implementation you use (which may be below the second).

A better approach would be to use C++11 [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) :

```
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t = high_resolution_clock::now();
...
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
long elapsed_milisecs = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t).count();
```

However, there's then a second issue: although this is portable and precise, you are bound to the **limits of clock resolution of your operating system**.

On windows for example, this clock resolution is of [15 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution).  Anything below 15 ms might appear as a duration of 0.

The easiest way to improve your time measurement, especially in the case of benchmarks, could be to increase the number of iterations your measure.  Instead of performing the measured code once, measure the time for thousands of successive iterations, and compute the average time per iteration.

A less portable approach would be to use native OS high resolution timers, to circumvent library implementation limitations:

- For windows, you could use `QueryPerformanceCounter` as explained in [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/12/28/high-resolution-timer-for-c.aspx).
- For linux you could use `clock_gettime()` as explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538609/high-resolution-timer-with-c-and-linux).

Comment: where does .count() come from?

Comment: It's a member of chrono::duration (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/duration/).  By the way, I think chrono::milliseconds would be better (I have a using clause in my code).