# How to create a high resolution timer in Linux to measure program performance?

Tags: c, linux, timer, precision, high-resolution-clock

I'm trying to compare GPU to CPU performance. For the NVIDIA GPU I've been using the `cudaEvent_t` types to get a very precise timing.

For the CPU I've been using the following code:

```
// Timers
clock_t start, stop;
float elapsedTime = 0;

// Capture the start time

start = clock();

// Do something here
.......

// Capture the stop time
stop = clock();
// Retrieve time elapsed in milliseconds
elapsedTime = (float)(stop - start) / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0f;
```

Apparently, that piece of code is only good if you're counting in seconds. Also, the results sometime come out quite strange.

Does anyone know of some way to create a high resolution timer in Linux?

Comment: See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700392/high-resolution-timing-part-of-your-code

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Check out [`clock_gettime`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), which is a POSIX interface to high-resolution timers.

If, having read the manpage, you're left wondering about the difference between `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, see [Difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic)

See the following page for a complete example: http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end);

int main()
{
    timespec time1, time2;
    int temp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
    for (int i = 0; i< 242000000; i++)
        temp+=temp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
    cout<<diff(time1,time2).tv_sec<<":"<<diff(time1,time2).tv_nsec<<endl;
    return 0;
}

timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end)
{
    timespec temp;
    if ((end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)<0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec-1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear about what I've read, can you give me an example on how you would use clock_gettime to find the time elapsed in nanoseconds?

Comment: @seljuq70: I've added a link to a complete example.

Comment: OP was posted C, but your answer is C++. Still useful, but not on my ZedBoard that has no C++ libs :D To fix, prefix the timespec with struct and strip out the couts.

Comment: so the answer explicitly speaks about `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` but we end up with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` in the code sample? Can someone clear this up? What's the one to go?

Comment: @itMaxence

Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527632/9732482

Comment: my point was, speaking of a difference between A and B makes no sense if you end up having C in the sample code. (without speaking once about the `C` part)

Comment: According to this linked man page, `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` measures time "consumed by this process". Which depending on the use case may not actually be what you want. If the process is stalling due to blocking syscalls or whatever then I would like to measure that too.

Answer (score 22):

To summarise information presented so far, these are the two functions required for typical applications.

```
#include <time.h>

// call this function to start a nanosecond-resolution timer
struct timespec timer_start(){
    struct timespec start_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start_time);
    return start_time;
}

// call this function to end a timer, returning nanoseconds elapsed as a long
long timer_end(struct timespec start_time){
    struct timespec end_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end_time);
    long diffInNanos = (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) * (long)1e9 + (end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec);
    return diffInNanos;
}
```

Here is an example of how to use them in timing how long it takes to calculate the variance of a list of input.

```
struct timespec vartime = timer_start();  // begin a timer called 'vartime'
double variance = var(input, MAXLEN);  // perform the task we want to time
long time_elapsed_nanos = timer_end(vartime);
printf("Variance = %f, Time taken (nanoseconds): %ld\n", variance, time_elapsed_nanos);
```

Comment: Aren't you ignoring the `tv_sec` of the `timespec`? Also, why `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` rather than `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`?

Comment: The poster is comparing CPU to GPU performance. You are honestly giving code getting the CPU time. CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID. This means he will get speed ups many orders of magnitude. For CPU/GPU performance (this question) always use wall time. Remove this answer.

Comment: @TimZaman Yep, realtime might be better in the poster's use case. I'm not going to take down an answer though, obviously people have found it useful. Cheers.

Comment: Before using CLOCK_PROGRESS_CPUTIME_ID you shoud run `grep constant_tsc /proc/cpuinfo` to understand how this clock works. If you CPU does not support *constant_tsc*, the time reflects actual CPU clock cycles. If the flag is set, the clock is adjusted to account for current CPU frequency. I give this a -1 because *time_elapsed_nanos* is incorrectly calculated. [This](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/) may be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct timespec t;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);
```

there is also CLOCK_REALTIME_HR, but I'm not sure whether it makes any difference..

Comment: And I am not sure if `CLOCK_REALTIME_HR` is suported. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094769/clock-realtime-nanosecond-precision-support-in-kernel).

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in wall time (how much time actually elapses) or cycle count (how many cycles)?  In the first case, you should use something like `gettimeofday`.

The highest resolution timer uses the `RDTSC` x86 assembly instruction.  However, this measures clock ticks, so you should be sure that power saving mode is disabled.

The wiki page for TSC gives a few examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Comment: On a modern CPU, `rdtsc` correlates 1:1 with wall-clock time, not core clock cycles.  It doesn't pause when your process (or the whole CPU) is sleeping, and it runs at constant frequency regardless of turbo / power-saving.  Use performance counters to measure actual core clock cycles.  e.g. `perf stat awk 'BEGIN {for (i=0 ; i<10000000; i++){}}'`.

Comment: I am actually interested in wall time. Your reply hit the spot!

Comment: Is it possible to link your reply to my original comment?

Answer (score 1):

After reading this thread I started testing the code for clock_gettime against c++11's chrono and they don't seem to match.

There is a huge gap between them!

The **std::chrono::seconds(1)** seems to be equivalent to **~70,000** of the **clock_gettime**

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end);
timespec get_cpu_now_time();
std::vector<timespec> get_start_end_pairs();
std::vector<timespec> get_start_end_pairs2();
void output_deltas(const std::vector<timespec> &start_end_pairs);

//=============================================================
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello waiter" << std::endl; // flush is intentional
    std::vector<timespec> start_end_pairs = get_start_end_pairs2();
    output_deltas(start_end_pairs);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//=============================================================
std::vector<timespec> get_start_end_pairs()
{
    std::vector<timespec> start_end_pairs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        start_end_pairs.push_back(get_cpu_now_time());
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        start_end_pairs.push_back(get_cpu_now_time());
    }

    return start_end_pairs;
}


//=============================================================
std::vector<timespec> get_start_end_pairs2()
{
    std::mutex mu;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    std::vector<timespec> start_end_pairs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        workers.emplace_back([&]()->void {
            auto start_time = get_cpu_now_time();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            auto end_time = get_cpu_now_time();
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(mu);
            start_end_pairs.emplace_back(start_time);
            start_end_pairs.emplace_back(end_time);
        });
    }

    for (auto &worker: workers) {
        if (worker.joinable()) {
            worker.join();
        }
    }

    return start_end_pairs;
}

//=============================================================
void output_deltas(const std::vector<timespec> &start_end_pairs)
{
    std::cout << "size: " << start_end_pairs.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto it_start = start_end_pairs.begin(); it_start < start_end_pairs.end(); it_start += 2)
    {
        auto it_end = it_start + 1;
        auto delta = diff(*it_start, *it_end);

        std::cout
                << std::setw(2)
                << std::setfill(' ')
                << std::distance(start_end_pairs.begin(), it_start) / 2
                << " Waited ("
                << delta.tv_sec
                << "\ts\t"
                << std::setw(9)
                << std::setfill('0')
                << delta.tv_nsec
                << "\tns)"
                << std::endl;
    }
}

//=============================================================
timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end)
{
    timespec temp;
    temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
    temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;

    if (temp.tv_nsec < 0) {
        --temp.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec += 1000000000;
    }
    return temp;
}

//=============================================================
timespec get_cpu_now_time()
{
    timespec now_time;
    memset(&now_time, 0, sizeof(timespec));
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &now_time);

    return now_time;
}
```

output:

```
Hello waiter
 0 Waited (0    s       000843254       ns)
 1 Waited (0    s       000681141       ns)
 2 Waited (0    s       000685119       ns)
 3 Waited (0    s       000674252       ns)
 4 Waited (0    s       000714877       ns)
 5 Waited (0    s       000624202       ns)
 6 Waited (0    s       000746091       ns)
 7 Waited (0    s       000575267       ns)
 8 Waited (0    s       000860157       ns)
 9 Waited (0    s       000827479       ns)
10 Waited (0    s       000612959       ns)
11 Waited (0    s       000534818       ns)
12 Waited (0    s       000553728       ns)
13 Waited (0    s       000586501       ns)
14 Waited (0    s       000627116       ns)
15 Waited (0    s       000616725       ns)
16 Waited (0    s       000616507       ns)
17 Waited (0    s       000641251       ns)
18 Waited (0    s       000683380       ns)
19 Waited (0    s       000850205       ns)
```

Comment: I guess ++temp.tv_sec; is a type and you meant --temp.tv_sec; in the diff function.

Comment: it is not a type, when I subtract the 2 structs, I take into account that there might be a **carry over**

Comment: Yes, understood that. But when you do the carry from sec to nsec, you should subtract 1 tothe  seconds field and sum 1000000000 (1s) to the nsec field.
Let's say `(10s and 900ns) - (5s and 1000ns)` --> `5s and -100ns` --> `4s and (-100+10^9)ns`. The last step decreases the sec, thus doing the carry.

Comment: Yes correct, I fixed the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

[**`clock_gettime(2)`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Comment: `clock_gettime` is preferable as it gets you nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

epoll implemention:
https://github.com/ielife/simple-timer-for-c-language

use like this:

```
timer_server_handle_t *timer_handle = timer_server_init(1024);
if (NULL == timer_handle) {
    fprintf(stderr, "timer_server_init failed\n");
    return -1;
}
ctimer timer1;
    timer1.count_ = 3;
    timer1.timer_internal_ = 0.5;
    timer1.timer_cb_ = timer_cb1;
    int *user_data1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *user_data1 = 100;
    timer1.user_data_ = user_data1;
    timer_server_addtimer(timer_handle, &timer1);

    ctimer timer2;
    timer2.count_ = -1;
    timer2.timer_internal_ = 0.5;
    timer2.timer_cb_ = timer_cb2;
    int *user_data2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *user_data2 = 10;
    timer2.user_data_ = user_data2;
    timer_server_addtimer(timer_handle, &timer2);

    sleep(10);

    timer_server_deltimer(timer_handle, timer1.fd);
    timer_server_deltimer(timer_handle, timer2.fd);
    timer_server_uninit(timer_handle);
```