# Why doesnt the clock work? Its stuck at 0.000000000.

Tags: c, clock, fibonacci

http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/5089/itfib.png  Its stuck at 0.000000000 on all results. I posted this up before and people were able to get a number on it but every time I try, it always gives me those 0s.

```
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/file.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( )
{
  int j=1, fib, n, i=1, k=0;
  int choice;
  float x,y,z;

  printf("input the fib number you want: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  x = clock(); //start clock

  while (k <=n)
  {
    fib = i + j;
    i = j;
    j = fib;
    ++k;

    printf( "The fib number is %d\n ", fib);
  }

  y = clock(); // end clock
  z = (y - x) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  printf("\n\nThe execution time was: %.15f", z);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how fast is this running? `clock()` only measures CPU time taken by your process (not wall clock time), and if `clock()`'s resolution sucks on your system, you'll get about 0 seconds running time...

Comment: Three people have already overlooked this and made wrong comments. So for anyone who reads this question: **`x` and `y` are already `float`s**. *There is no integer division happening here*.

Comment: Have you tried making `n` really large? I made `n` about `10000` and `z` was about `1.135000000000000`

Comment: lol 10000 made the program loop non stop with random numbers.

Comment: @naminate They are not random - they are the product of integer overflow.  You will note it is the same sequence of 'random' numbers every time.  If you use a different data type you will get different results.

Comment: I used the same clock function in another program to print a word 5 times and I was able to get a number.. but why doesnt this work?? >:[

Comment: I was not able to get it on the recursive fibonacci either.

Comment: @Naminate, Just to make sure, make your while loop as follows, `while(k < n){ k++; }` and input `n` as `100000`. Then tell us what your output is.

Comment: @AnishRam 100000 gave me 0.150 < the rest are 0s. Yay! So now I know the clock is working.. So its just my CPU thats being too good? >o<

Comment: I guess your CPU takes very little clock cycles to perform these tasks. I would say if your `n` is always going to be low (~100), then use a clock which has higher granularity like the one suggested in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6749766/1383051). The clock you use measures time based on the amount of CPU cycles it took to perform the task.

Answer (score 1):

With `n=30`, your program does such a tiny amount of work that it will show up as zero time with a coarse `clock` granularity. On some systems, `clock` ticks once every 10ms. Assuming you have reasonably fast console I/O, you are probably in the *tens- or hundreds- of microseconds* range, and are probably spending 99.99% of the time in `printf`.

Try inputting a larger number like 1000000. Then you should get something nonzero.

Comment: Like Anish Ram said. I tried to put 10000 in and I got a nonstop loop.

Comment: @Naminate: It's not *nonstop*, it's just long-running. (You are also likely to see a lot of garbage values pop out because of integer overflow).

Comment: @Naminate, This answer exactly. First just make sure your timing works. Then debug the integer overflows. Of course, if you have a constraint that `n` is always a low integer value, then you needn't worry about integer overflows.

Comment: Well, you can't really "debug" the integer overflows; there's no way to avoid them without a big integer implementation. :)

Comment: Haha by debug I meant solve that problem. Bad usage of the word "debug" I admit

Comment: Yea. My bad. I decided to let it run and it came to an end 2 mins later lol.

Comment: But why is that I was able to get a time on a program that only prints a word 5 times rather than this program?? Doesn't this program take longer?

Comment: @Naminate: and when it came to an end, was the clock zero?

Comment: Scroll up a little. I posted the results that Anish asked on top. But no. I was able to get a number.

Comment: "@AnishRam 100000 gave me 0.150 < the rest are 0s. Yay! So now I know the clock is working.. So its just my CPU thats being too good? >o<"

Comment: @Naminate, Did you test that word printing program on the same computer as the one you're using to test this fibonacci program?

Comment: @AnishRam Yes. I am using Linux for both programs. Using the same computer as well.

Comment: When I did the word program, I got the result as like 0.000200000 somewhere like that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
struct timeval start, end;
long mtime, secs, usecs;    

gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
// your processing.
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
secs  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
usecs = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
mtime = ((secs) * 1000 + usecs/1000.0) + 0.5;
printf("Elapsed time: %ld millisecs\n", mtime);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I rather not change the code for clock since my professor is the one who gave out the code to use in this program.