# Better timer than mpi_Wtime

Tags: timer, mpi

My mpi_wtime has resolution of 1e-6 seconds which is not good enough for me? What are pros and cons of using other timers like gettimeoftheday?

Comment: `gettimeofday` also "only" has has microsecond resolution at best.

Comment: hmm. Yes. Any other alternative?

Comment: High-resolution timers are very platform-dependent. You'll need to provide more details. (And consider that your question has almost certainly been addressed before; [here's a Linux answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749621/high-resolution-timer-in-linux).)