# Linux high resolution timer in multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, timer

It seems the Linux high resolution timer starts counting within the scope of each thread - not globally in the application.

I tried using CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID but it gives me that thread behavior?

> ```
>    CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID (since Linux 2.6.12)
>           High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU.
>
>    CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID (since Linux 2.6.12)
>           Thread-specific CPU-time clock.
> ```

Looking for a high resolution timer across threads.
(The global timers are in milli seconds while the high resolution in nanoseconds.)

How do I get high resolution time in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: Doe it need to be human time or compute time. Human time is in seconds and compute time is in instructions?

Comment: @mikhail: compute time as much as possible, looking for nano/micro seconds

Comment: What do you mean by *starts within the scope of a threat*? What have you tried so far? According to [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), Linux provides a high-resolution per-process timer from the CPU.

Comment: @oswald: it seems that the time returned is relative from the start of the thread.

Comment: @oswald: tried CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, gives me thread behavior...

Comment: There is a way that you can get access to the internal x86 timer registers. If I was writing a profile I would use them. They are completely worthless for things like hardware synchronization because modern CPUs change clock so you can't get a human number from them. They are called RTIMERs or something like that. If I could remember I would post an answer.

Comment: @P.S. Have you considered `getTimeofday` which gives resolution in `microseconds`? Ref: http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday

Comment: @mikhail: is that the one that is the cpu clock count, I think that one will change with the speed step technology....?

Comment: @ganesh: that may work....thanks

Comment: @P.S., yes but if you are writing a program that tells you the percentage that the program was in a certain function is this is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with `getTimeofday` which should give time in the resolution of `microseconds` (Reference: [Linux Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday))

You may also want to refer to this question: [How to create a high resolution timer in Linux to measure program performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749621/high-resolution-timer-in-linux?rq=1)