# Getting timestamp with date and time including microseconds

Tags: c, windows, time

For an error-logbook I want to create a timestamp with date and time, including microseconds. It should have the form 2016.07.19 13:59:31:123.456

I found a lot of examples of `time_t`, but the resolution is only seconds...

Comment: The microchip tag is likely misplaced. This question is unrelated to microchip pic microcontrollers.

Comment: You're looking for a _high resolution timer_. Recommend taking a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749621/how-to-create-a-high-resolution-timer-in-linux-to-measure-program-performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gettimeofday`:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
....
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
```

Where `struct timeval` is defined as:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

You can then use `gmtime` to split the seconds part:

```
struct tm *ts = gmtime(&tv.tv_sec);
```

Where `struct tm` is defined as:

> ```
>           struct tm {
>               int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
>               int tm_min;         /* minutes */
>               int tm_hour;        /* hours */
>               int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
>               int tm_mon;         /* month */
>               int tm_year;        /* year */
>               int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
>               int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
>               int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
>           };
> ```
>
> The members of the tm structure are:
>
> - tm_sec The  number of seconds after the minute, normally in the range 0
>               to 59, but can be up to 60 to allow for leap seconds.
> - tm_min The number of minutes after the hour, in the range 0 to 59.
> - tm_hour
>               The number of hours past midnight, in the range 0 to 23.
> - tm_mday
>               The day of the month, in the range 1 to 31.
> - tm_mon The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.
> - tm_year
>               The number of years since 1900.
> - tm_wday
>               The number of days since Sunday, in the range 0 to 6.
> - tm_yday
>               The number of days since January 1, in the range 0 to 365.
> - tm_isdst
>               A flag that indicates whether daylight saving time is in  effect
>               at the time described.  The value is positive if daylight saving
>               time is in effect, zero if it is not, and negative if the infor-
>               mation is not available.

EDIT:

Windows doesn't have `gettimeofday`.  Here's an implementation you can use:

```
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
{
    const unsigned __int64 epoch_diff = 11644473600000000;
    unsigned __int64 tmp;
    FILETIME t;

    if (tv) {
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&t);

        tmp = 0;
        tmp |= t.dwHighDateTime;
        tmp <<= 32;
        tmp |= t.dwLowDateTime;

        tmp /= 10;
        tmp -= epoch_diff;
        tv->tv_sec = (long)(tmp / 1000000);
        tv->tv_usec = (long)(tmp % 1000000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The members of the tm structure are:" describes the _minimum_ set of members.  The C spec uses "The tm structure shall contain at least the following members ..."  `gettimeofday()` is not a standard library function.  C does have `timespec_get()`, yet I am uncertain of its popularity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @nobody Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed the Enter buttom and my comment was sent already. I wanted to write:   Thanks for your reply. I'm using a Windows notebook and a XC16 compiler. I don't have the <sys/time.h>. Where can I get it and how to install it?

Comment: @nobody Windows doesn't have `gettimeofday`, however I included an implementation you can use.