# Vectorization with gcc and openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, vectorization

With g++, I have often achieved effective parallel speed improvements using simple openmp annotations, but not with the following near trivial vectorization example. In am using g++ 7 on Ubuntu 16.04, and understand that [openmp comes with the compiler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144352/how-can-i-install-openmp-in-ubuntu).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    const unsigned N = 10000000;
    float* table1 = new float[N];
    float* table2 = new float[N];
    float* table3 = new float[N];

    std::mt19937 RND(123);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0,1);

    for (unsigned n = 0; n < N; ++n) { /*Initialize table1 and table2*/
        table1[n]=dist(RND);
        table2[n]=dist(RND);
    }

    auto start = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    
    for(unsigned k=0;k<500;k++) { /*Do inner loop a lot*/

        //#pragma omp parallel for
        //#pragma omp simd
        for (unsigned n = 0; n < N; ++n) /*VECTORIZE ME*/
        { 
            table3[n]=table1[n]+table2[n];
        }

    }

    auto end = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    std::cout << "Time " << end.count() - start.count() << std::endl;
        
    for (unsigned n = 0; n < N; ++n) { /*Use* the result.*/
        if (abs(table3[n]-(table1[n]+table2[n]))>0.01) {
            throw false;
        }
    }

    delete table1; delete table2; delete table3;
}
```

For a baseline, compiling `g++ -o "openmp-sandpit" "openmp-sandpit.cpp"` and running, yields a time of **14662ms** and `top`s at 25% (I have I7 with *four* processors, and am running `top` with irix mode *off*).

Next we invoke `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3`, achieving 8524ms, 7473ms and 7376ms, respectively, all  with `top` 25%.

- **Secondary Question #1** *Has g++ made use of SIMD vectorization in achieving these optimizations?*

Next we uncomment `#pragma omp parallel for` and compile with the `-fopenmp`, achieving 7553ms and a `top` of 100%. *Additionally* adding g++ optimization flags `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3`, achieves 8411ms, 7463ms and 7415ms, respectively, all  with `top` just below 100%.

Notice that openmp on four cores (top 100%) achieves 7553ms which is *worse* than *vanilla* g++ at `-O2` and `-O3`, and similar to `-O1`.

- **Secondary Question #2** *Why is openmp,when using all four cores (`top` 100%), outperformed by optimized g++ on a single core (`top` 25%)?*

Finally, replacing the comment`//#pragma omp parallel for`, uncommenting `#pragma omp simd` and compiling with the single option `-fopenmp-simd` achieves (a terrible) **15006ms** with an expected `top` of 25%. *Additionally* adding g++ optimization flags `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3`, achieves 7911ms, 7350ms and 7364ms, respectively, all  with `top` of 25%.

- **Main Question** *What is wrong with my openmp-simd code? Why is it not vectorizing?*

If I could vectorize the inner `n` loop (openmp-simd), I could then parallelize the outer `k` loop (openmp), and should get a 2x-4x speed up for the outer loop (over the four cores), and a 4x-8x speed up for the inner loop (SIMD on each core), achieving a 8x-32x speed improvement. Surely?

[... It appears that g++ [vectorization is turned on by default on -O3](https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/series/vectorization-in-gcc/). This I have tested and verified ...]

[...
The best result obtains, by avoiding openmp-simd. The following code uses openmp to split to 4 cores and the g++ auto vectorization.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int k=0;k<500;k++) { /*Do inner loop a lot*/

        for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n) /*VECTORIZE ME*/
        { 
            table3[n]=table1[n]+table2[n];
        }

    }
```

Compiling `g++-7 **-O3** **-march=native** **-fopenmp**` (thanks to @Marc Glisse for -march=native) yields **3912**. No other combination comes close.
...]

Comment: Try to change the `N` from unsigned to signed, as well as `n` in your inner loop when trying to use OMP `parallel for` pragma, worked for me under MSVC (accelerated twice from vanilla version)

Comment: I tried that for both the openmp and the openmp-simd versions and no change. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Don't forget `-march=native` to use non-trivial vector instructions...

Comment: #1: `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize` is slower, so yes it did benefit from vectorization. `-fopt-info` lists the vectorized loops.

Comment: @Marc Glisse Thanks. I have just explored -march=native and it is certainly helping with g++ auto vectorization. I can see the change in the assembly instructions. This is leading me to opt for openmp divide into cores and then g++ auto vectorization per core. I have read that openmp turns off gcc auto vectorization, but I will explore.

Comment: #3 Of course you get terrible performance if you don't pass any `-O*` flag, -fopenmp-simd doesn't replace them, it comes on top of them and is useless without them.

Comment: Is the answer to #2 that openmp is spreading to 4 cores but now gcc is no longer auto vectorizing?

Comment: #2 the overhead (including worse optimization) of using openmp threads is too much, for too little work in each thread. Make N 100 times larger to see some benefit.

Comment: omp simd shouldn't have any advantage here.  As the arrays are defined locally, there is no aliasing to suppress either by that pragma or by __restrict ( which might often be preferred).  It's true that g++ apparently doesn't implement omp parallel simd but it's hard to draw conclusions when you have that k loop which the compiler is entitled to eliminate.

Comment: The k loop is effective in all cases. I agree it can be removed, but it is not. Hence I can use it for timing. I will change the loop to make it "consequential" and ensure I depend on the "consequence" but suspect the result will be the same.

Comment: Secondary Question #1 : Use -S to see assembly code and if `xmm`, `ymm` or `zmm` registers are used for each section you can understand it is SIMDized or not. Secondary Question #2: you must run your program many times and get the smallest time see this timing [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579555/how-to-measure-the-elapsead-time-below-nanosecond-for-x86)

Comment: Use `-fopt-info-vec-omp-optimized-missed` to get a vectorization report.