# Control loop time with usleep

Tags: c++, linux, time, gettimeofday

I try to make sure the execution time of each loop to 10ms with usleep , but sometimes it exceeds 10ms.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, is it proper to use ***usleep*** and ***gettimeofday*** in this case?

Please help my find out what i missed.

> Result: 0.0127289
>   0.0136499
>   0.0151598
>   0.0114031
>   0.014801

```
double tvsecf(){
     struct timeval tv;
     double asec;

     gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
     asec = tv.tv_usec;
     asec /= 1e6;
     asec += tv.tv_sec;

     return asec;
}
int main(){
    double t1 ,t2;
    t1 = tvsecf();
    for(;;){
        t2= tvsecf();
        if(t2-t1 >= 0.01){
            if(t2-t1 >= 0.011)
                cout << t2-t1 <<endl;
            t1 = tvsecf();
        }
        usleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you have to decide which language you are using…

Comment: Usually sleeps are only guaranteed to sleep for *at least* as long as you asked for - they may sleep longer.

Comment: I think `nanosleep` is the preferred sleep.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: If you really need to do something every 10ms without fail (and don't just think you do), then you're going to need to run your program on a real-time OS

Comment: Just sleeping for a fixed amount of time at the end of the loop disregards the time you *already spent* running the top of the loop. There is no way that strategy would run each iteration on a fixed 10ms beat unless the time spent in the rest of the loop is zero. At the very least you would want to sleep for "10ms - time_already_spent_this_iteration".

Comment: The reason i want to control the loop execution time is to control adc sample rate, in this case 10ms to achieve 100sps sample rate

Comment: Sorry i didn't describe my actual problem first, what i'm looking for is more close to the average iteration time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the loop overhead (which is generally unknown) from constantly accumulating error, you can sleep *until* a time **point**, instead of *for* a time **duration**.  Using C++'s `<chrono>` and `<thread>` libraries, this is incredibly easy:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t0 = steady_clock::now() + 10ms;
    for (;;)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_until(t0);
        t0 += 10ms;
    }
}
```

One can dress this up with more calls to `steady_clock::now()` in order to ascertain the time between iterations, and perhaps more importantly, the *average* iteration time:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using dsec = duration<double>;
    auto t0 = steady_clock::now() + 10ms;
    auto t1 = steady_clock::now();
    auto t2 = t1;
    constexpr auto N = 1000;
    dsec avg{0};
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_until(t0);
        t0 += 10ms;
        t2 = steady_clock::now();
        dsec delta = t2-t1;
        std::cout << delta.count() << "s\n";
        avg += delta;
        t1 = t2;
    }
    avg /= N;
    cout << "avg = " << avg.count() << "s\n";
}
```

Above I've added to the loop overhead by doing more things within the loop.  However the loop is still going to wake up *about* every 10ms.  Sometimes the OS will wake the thread late, but next time the loop automatically adjusts itself to sleep for a shorter time.  Thus the average iteration rate self-corrects to 10ms.

On my machine this just output:

```
...
0.0102046s
0.0128338s
0.00700504s
0.0116826s
0.00785826s
0.0107023s
0.00912614s
0.0104725s
0.010489s
0.0112545s
0.00906409s
avg = 0.0100014s
```

Comment: Yes!  The average iteration time is the most important for my application.

Answer (score 0):

From the [usleep man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html):

> The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers.

If you need high resolution: with C on Unix (or Linux) check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6749766/9973881) that explains how to use high resolution timers using clock_gettime.

Edit: As mentioned by Tobias [nanosleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) may be a better option:

```
Compared to sleep(3) and usleep(3), nanosleep() has the following
advantages: it provides a higher resolution for specifying the sleep
interval; POSIX.1 explicitly specifies that it does not interact with
signals; and it makes the task of resuming a sleep that has been
interrupted by a signal handler easier.
```

Comment: Also from usleep man page. POSIX.1-2001 declares this function obsolete use nanosleep(2) instead. POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of usleep()

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee 10ms loop time.
All sleeping functions sleeps for at least wanted time.
For a portable solution use [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    for (;;) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{10});
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = end-start;
        std::cout << "Waited " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";
    }
}
```

Depending on what you are trying to do take a look at [Howard Hinnants](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) date library.