# Taking the difference between two changing times

Tags: c, time, timer

I want to subtract two times from each other that are of the format `MM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS.ns`.

This is a code snippet of what is pasted at the top and bottom of my program since I am taking the overall time of a program for individual calculations:

```c
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
struct tm* start_timer = localtime(&start.tv_sec);
size_t ns1 = strftime(timer, 100, "%B %e, %G %R:%S.", start_timer);

snprintf(timer + ns1, 100 - ns1, "%.9ld", start.tv_nsec);
fprintf(fout, "%s", timer);

/*---------------------------------
 Main function doing calculations
-----------------------------------*/

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
struct tm* stop_timer = localtime(&end.tv_sec);
size_t ns2 = strftime(timer, 100, "%B %e, %G %R:%S.", stop_timer);

snprintf(timer + ns2, 100 - ns2, "%.9ld", end.tv_nsec);
fprintf(fout, "%s", timer);
```

Once the calculations are done, the start time and end times are printed (just as an example):

```
Start time: April 12, 2022 13:45:29.123456789
End time: April 12, 2022 13:45:51.234567890
```

Basically, these values are constantly changing based on when I run, and how long the program runs. What I want to do is **take the difference between these times to report an overall time for the entire program. By this I mean I want it to print like this:**

```
Overall time: 03:12.345678901
```

How do I achieve this? I was thinking that I would have to use `strptime` for this, and I know that `difftime` will be a player, but I'm not entirely sure about how I'd do that since the variables are constantly changing. I would assume to store these into variables, but I get an error saying this:

```
assignment to ‘time_t’ {aka ‘long int’} from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: If you have two `time_t` values you can use [`difftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime) to calculate the difference in seconds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I also want to calculate minutes, as well. Would I still be able to use ```difftime``` for that, as well?

Comment: Also note that while `time_t` is really an opaque type whose representation is implementation defined, on most systems (especially PC-like systems like Windows, macOS and Linux) it's an integer type whose value is a number of seconds since an epoch. So almost everywhere you can just subtract the two `time_t` values to get the difference in seconds.

Comment: `difftime(time1, time2) / 60`?

Comment: @tal_code Given "MM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS.ns", is that universal time?  (looks like local time given `localtime()`) If local time, it is **always** _standard_ time and never _daylight savings time_?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica since my windows computer switches to daylight savings when it comes, the time that is printed seems to be in daylight savings, too. This is also local time, yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a high resolution timer in Linux to measure program performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749621/how-to-create-a-high-resolution-timer-in-linux-to-measure-program-performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find time between `start` and `end` subtract both members.

```
double diff_seconds = difftime(end.tv_sec, start.tv_sec) + 
    (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1.0e9;
```

> I want it to print like this: "Overall time: 03:12.345678901"

```
double min = trunc(diff_seconds / 60);
double sec = diff_seconds - min * 60;
// Possible format - needs checking
printf("Overall time: %02.0f:%02.9f\n", min, sec);
```

---

Due to rounding, I am wondering if "xxxx.60.000000000" is possible - hmmm....

That is possible when `diff_seconds` is more than say, 17 years, so for OP, not a big concern.

Alternative code could insure `diff_seconds * 10e9` fits in a `long long` and then process the nano_seconds as a large integer - not shown.