# How to time event in C++?

Tags: c++

I'd like to be able to get number of nanoseconds it takes to do something in my C++ program.

Object creation, time for a function to do it's thing etc.

In `Java`, we'd do something along the lines of:

```
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // stuff
    long diff = (System.currentTimeMillis() - now);
```

How would you do the same in C++?

Comment: time.h http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/

Comment: I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/3287323) timer class a little while ago - it's far from perfect but it could be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<chrono>` library in standard C++ provides the best way to do this. This library provides a standard, type safe, generic API for clocks.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;

    auto start = clock::now();
    // stuff
    auto end = clock::now();
    std::cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end-start).count() << "ns\n";
}
```

The actual resolution of the clock will vary between implementations, but this code will always show results in nanoseconds, as accurately as possible given the implementation's tick period.

Comment: I am getting `error: ‘std::chrono’ has not been declared` error. What might be going on please?

Comment: @Jam You may be using a standard library implementation from before C++11. What compiler version and standard library are you using?

Comment: `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1`, not sure about the version of standard library. How can i find it out?

Comment: gcc 4.2 is far too old to support this. I'm guessing you're at least on OS X 10.6, in which case you should be able to use clang++ with the arguments -std=c++11 and -stdlib=libc++ to enable C++11 including the chrono library.

Comment: Hmm ... I just updated the command line dev tools a few days ago. I am on OSX10.8, mountain lion. How can i upgrade the compiler please? Also, is this feature an exclusive feature of c11?

Comment: Yes, chrono was introduced with C++11, but many implementations have it even before being completely C++11 compliant. The llvm-gcc compiler is not going to be updated past 4.2, and I think it has been removed starting with Xcode 4.4 (though a previous install may remain), so you have to switch to a different compiler. Use the command clang++ instead of g++ or whatever command you've been using. Also enable C++11 mode with the compiler flags -std=c++11 and -stdlib=libc++.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can do it using chrono library where -

> Class template std::chrono::duration represents a time interval.
>   It consists of a count of ticks of type Rep and a tick period, where the tick period is a compile-time rational constant representing the number of seconds from one tick to the next.

Currently implemented in GCC 4.5.1. (not yet in VC++). See sample code from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) on Ideone.com [execution time of a function call](http://ideone.com/3VobQ)

Comment: `<chrono>` is in the VS2012 RC although I think the high_resolution_clock's tick is only 100ns. It should be better on other platforms. libc++ on OS X has ns resolution. I'm not sure about gcc or libstdc++.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `clock` and `clock_t`. For the resolution you're talking about, I don't think there's native support in C++. To get meaningful values, you'll have to time multiple calls or constructions, or use a profiler (desired).

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered many times.

- [How do I do High Resolution Timing in C++ on Windows?](http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsi2/a/timing.htm)
- [C++ obtaining milliseconds time on Linux — clock() doesn't seem to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588307/c-obtaining-milliseconds-time-on-linux-clock-doesnt-seem-to-work-properl)
- [High Resolution Timing Part of Your Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700392/high-resolution-timing-part-of-your-code)
- [High resolution timer with C++ and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538609/high-resolution-timer-with-c-and-linux?lq=1)

If you're using C++11 you can consider [`chrono`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/chrono/).

Comment: Unfortunately none of those give the right answer, `<chrono>`.

Comment: What do you mean "the right answer"? That is a C++11 feature, which the OP did not mention supporting.

Comment: Chrono is standard, provides type safety for both time points vs. durations and for units, and won't require a new API as higher resolutions become available, so in most cases I'd consider it a mistake to use clock_gettime(), clock(), gettimeofday(), QueryPerformanceFrequency(), etc.

Comment: The latest versions of all the major compilers support chrono. If someone needs to support an older compiler then they can mention that requirement. It's 2012 so IMO C++ == C++11 now.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this exact question earlier today. The best solution I have at the moment is to use SDL, and call:

```
uint32 a_time = SDL_GetTicks(); // Return uint32 count of milliseconds since SDL_Init was called
```

Although this is probably going to give you lots of overhead, even if you just init SDL with the timer functionality. (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER).

Hope this helps you - I settled for this as a solution because it is portable.