# How to measure time in ms in c program

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, time, mutex

I need to measure time of entering and ending of a mutex of a code so I write this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

pthread_t tid[4];
int counter;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    time_t stime=time(NULL);

    unsigned long i = 0;
    counter += 1;
    printf("\n Job %d started\n", counter);

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFF);i++){
//      printf("%d", i); //this is just wait
    }
    printf("\n Job %d finished\n", counter);

    time_t etime=time(NULL);
    printf("time : %ld\n", difftime(etime, stime));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(i < 4)
    {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        i++;
    }

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[2], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[3], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

But the time I get is 0

Comment: Since `difftime` is returning a `double`, the printf should be:
`printf("time : %lf\n", difftime(etime, stime));`

Comment: Depending on how much you optimized your code, `0` may be the right answer to withing the resolution of your timer.

Comment: That may be because your code is running so quick, there is no measurable time difference.  Try to do something time consuming inside your for loop - complex math for example.

Comment: @Trenin or `sleep(10)` ?

Comment: Or, use a smaller time granularity.

Comment: @infinitecolon - Ha! Yes!

Comment: @Trenin: The  difftime()  function  returns the number of seconds elapsed between time time1 and time time0, represented as a double. I need a function that return ms time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of timing things - "wall time", "CPU time" are two of them. There are different libraries to help you perform timing tasks. Here are a few:

For CPU TIME (if you have multiple threads on multiple CPUs, this will be "faster than the wall clock"):

```
#include <time.h>
clock_t startTime, stopTime;
double msecElapsed;
startTime = clock();
// thing that needs timing
stopTime = clock();
msecElapsed = (stopTime - startTime) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Note this *may* be capable of timing with microsecond accuracy - depends on the compiler and platform.

For ELAPSED (wall clock) time:

```
#include <sys/timeb.h>

struct timeb start, stop;
ftime(&start);
// thing that needs timing
ftime(&stop);
msecElapsed = timeDifference(&start, &stop);
```

You also need this function:

```
double timeDifference(struct timeb *start, struct timeb *stop) {
  return stop->time - start->time + 0.001 * (stim->millitm - start->millitm);
}
```

If you are using OMP to facilitate parallel processing, it has a handy function

```
#include <omp.h>
double startTime, stopTime;
startTime = omp_get_wtime();
// do things
stopTime = omp_get_wtime();
```

This typically times to microsecond accuracy (even if you didn't use any other OMP functions).

Finally - you might want to look at the answers to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700392/high-resolution-timing-part-of-your-code) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588307/c-obtaining-milliseconds-time-on-linux-clock-doesnt-seem-to-work-properl) for more information/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably get zero because the time that it takes to execute is too small and so the resolution of the timestamps are not granular enough as suggested by @Floris.

The `time()` function actually returns seconds since 1st Jan 1970, not milliseconds. After a quick google, it appears that a solution may be in the clock() function which provides a time to milliseconds level (untested):

```
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();
    // do stuff
    end = clock();

    std::cout << "Process took " << (1000 * double(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << "milliseconds." << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You code does not work

Comment: The resolution used by `clock()` is system dependend and could be determined as per incpecting `CLOCK_PER_SEC`. As the latter is also system dependend, using both together one is capabable measure time.

Comment: @mezgani: This is not a very constructive (error) report.

Comment: Cheers for the edit @alk