# How to calculate time execution and cpu speding for a function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have finished writing a function and I want to compare time and cpu execution of the function with other function. This is code to calculate time execution but I not sure it accuracy. Do you have accuracy code to calculate time and cpu spending for one function in C++?

```
//Only time execution. CPU spending?
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();

    for(int i=0;i<65536;i++)
    cout<<i<<endl;

    end = clock();
    cout << "Time required for execution: "
    << (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC
    << " seconds." << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know calculate the execution time of an algorithm in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949752/how-to-know-calculate-the-execution-time-of-an-algorithm-in-c)

Comment: Since you tagged this Visual-C++, have you tried the Visual Profiler ? (Not available in every version though).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Calculate Execution Time of a Code Snippet in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861294/how-to-calculate-execution-time-of-a-code-snippet-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

In C++11 you should use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` which under the hood uses the clock source with the smallest tick period provided by the system:

```
#include <chrono>

auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
//...
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
```

Comment: Sorry. I am using visual studio C++ 2010 . What is library that your code need include ?

Comment: @user2408476: I'm afraid I don't know how well Visual Studio supports C++11 features. If including `<chrono>` doesn't work, you may want either to use [`boost`](http://www.boost.org/) which provides a `high_resolution_clock` implementation, or Mats Petersson's `QueryPerformanceCounter` solution.

Comment: <chrono> is not supported in VC++2010. For high precision time measurements you should use QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: Is this the CPU time or computer time ?

Answer (score 1):

For this particular code, I'm pretty sure your code is quite OK.

For short periods, you may need to use more precise timing functions, such as Windows' [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get higher precision timing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of to get precise time estimates is to use an OpenMP function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main() {
    double dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    foo();
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("time in seconds %f\n", dtime);
}
```

In gcc compile with -fopenmp.  In visual studio turn on OpenMP support under C++/Language Support.  BTW, OpenMP now works in Visual Studio 2012 express.  For CPU time profiling you can try http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer/

Comment: it's quite absurd to measure time with a parallelization suite, but well: it works.

Comment: Why is it absurd?  The solution is cross platform, simple, accurate, and even works with threading.  What's not to like?