# Calculate execution time of a function in c++ (visual studio 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am coding in c++ and working on Visual Studio 2010. I am trying to compute the time that a function takes to execute, here is my code

```
        double sum=0;   
        clock_t start_s=clock();
        for(int j=1;j<size;j++)
        {
            int key=data[j];
            int i=j-1;
            while(i>=0 && data[i]>key)
            {
                data[i+1]=data[i];
                i=i-1;
            }
            data[i+1]=key;
        }
        clock_t stop_s=clock();
        sum=((double)(stop_s - start_s)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

but the problem is that the time computes to 0. How can I measure the time in even smaller unit

Comment: Hare is You Answer i think

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861294/how-to-calculate-execution-time-of-a-code-snippet-in-c

Comment: visual studio gives error on "int64" and "uint64"

Comment: Make the thing you measure take longer is the obvious option. If what you measure is very short you will nostly measure variability.

Answer (score 1):

The `clock()` will give you a resolution of 1 ms.
If you want a higher resolution, use the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Or, the hacky way: run your code a million times :D

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to run this code segment, say for 100,000 times then calculate the average time

```
 double sum=0;   
    clock_t start_s=clock();

 int x = 0;

 while (x < 100000)
 {
    for(int j=1;j<size;j++)
    {
        int key=data[j];
        int i=j-1;
        while(i>=0 && data[i]>key)
        {
            data[i+1]=data[i];
            i=i-1;
        }
        data[i+1]=key;
    }      
    x++;
  }
    clock_t stop_s=clock();
    sum=((double)(stop_s - start_s)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/100000; //average time
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `clock()` is returning millisecond resolution ticks on Windows.

To get better granularity you should use the Windows high-resolution performance counter. Call [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).