# Time for an algorithm to run

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to time my algorithm but the time always shows up as zero. Here is my code:

```
steady_clock::time_point start = steady_clock::now();
ReverseArray(list1, 1000000);
steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now();
auto totalTime = end - start;
cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(totalTime).count()<< "\n";
```

Comment: What does ReverseArray do, and do you use list1 afterwards? Could it be that the compiler is optimizing the code and removing the call?

Comment: Have you tried with a measure thiner than microseconds? Could be your algorithm, which is executed fast. Provide the code of that algorithm, just for the case.

Comment: For todays CPUs even a microsecond is a long time. Why not use a profiler tool?

Comment: I have tried using nanoseconds also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Calculate Execution Time of a Code Snippet in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861294/how-to-calculate-execution-time-of-a-code-snippet-in-c)

Comment: Or even: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer

Comment: Try running it a few hundred or thousand times in a loop, and divide the total time by the number of iterations. The exec time of a single iteration may be too fast for accurate timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows, use [this resource.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It is good for sub-microsecond accuracy. Use this:

```
LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);
ReverseArray(list1, 1000000);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;

ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
```

Comment: He may not be though, in which case he would need `<chrono>` or the boost library.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah Yes you're completely correct. In Windows, I've found the best accuracy with QPF, but obviously this will only work on Windows.

Comment: yeah the QPF could potentially achieve sub-microsecond accuracy (depending on the clock frequency)

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on Jack's answer: on Windows, **using Visual Studio up to 2013, [there is a bug in the standard library which makes chrono clocks unprecise](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/)**. The high resolution clock is an alias to the steady clock which is ok, but [the bug is that it have a very low resolution (around 8 ms last time I checked)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/). 
Therefore, to this day (04/2014), VS standard library can't be used for measuring time or even for time-sensitive concurrent data sharing mechanisms (like when relying on condition_variable.wait_for() or this_thread::sleep_for() functions). Personally I fixed this problem by using Boost implementation instead until it's fixed. As pointed by STL (the person who is in charge of the standard library in Microsoft)  in [the bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/) this should be fixed for the Visual Studio versions higher than 2013 (not the CTPs as they don't change the standard library).

What I mean is that your code is actually correct and cross-platform (except I would have used high_precision_clock instead), that specific implementation is buggy, but it works well with other implementations (GCC, Clang, Boost version of chrono and thread).
For example this works perfectly well on [GCC 4.8 (Coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

auto my_array = []{ 
        std::vector<long long> values( 100000 );
        long long last_value = 0;
        for( auto& value : values )
            value = last_value++;
        return values;
    }();


void some_work()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i ) // play with this count 
        std::reverse( begin(my_array), end(my_array) );
}


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    some_work();
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto totalTime = end - start;
    cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(totalTime).count()<< " microsecs \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Coliru return "95 microsecs" for me when trying with only one cycle in some_work().

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need more resolution:

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// Your code to be measured

auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto t = std::chrono::duration<double,std::milli>(t2-t1).count();

std::cout << "Time (ms):" << t << std::endl;
```