# Cuda: line of code not executed slowing down the program

Tags: c++, cuda

I am using Cuda with C++ to do some parallel computing. Recently, I noticed something that I cannot understand and I didn't find informations about it when looking for it. In my code, one line which is very seldom exectued (but needed) slows down the program even when it is not executed at all. Here is some code to make it more clear:

The class I created:

```
class Foo 
{ 
void myFunction(Foo *listFoo);
//some other functions that I need
...
int myAttribute;
//some other attributes that I need
...
}
```

The definition of myFunction:

```
void Foo::myFunction(Foo *listFoo)
{
//do some computations on the listFoo
if( condition seldom verified )
  {  myAttribute = myAttribute + 1; }
}
```

The global function:

```
__global__ void compute(Foo *listFoo, int numberOfFoo)
{
   int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
   if( i < numberOfFoo)
   {  listFoo[i].myFunction(listFoo); }
}
```

The host code:

```
compute<<<(numberOfFoo + 511)/512, 512>>> (listFoo, numberOfFoo)
```

The line slowing down everything is myAttribute = myAttribute + 1. Even when it is executed 0 times, the code is really slow compared to when the line is put in the comment. I tried to replace this line with a simple printf. The result is the same, the line is never executed but it slows down everything.

If you have any suggestion on the reason and on eventually how to solve this problem, it would be very much appreciated. My level in programing is not so advanced, so please use relatively easy explanations.

Thanks a lot

**First Edit**: few people requested the code, so here it is! I reduced it to 700 lines, I know it is still very long but not much would work if I keep removing some parts of it. It compiles without problems for me. All you have to do is press enter, wait few seconds and the time taken will be shown in the command window.

It is in the function findContactwithGrain() that the problem occurs. The line addContact(grainContact) is slowing down everything. On my computer, if this line is active, one computation takes around 3.5 sec. If I put it in comment, it takes 0.07 sec. That's a huge difference for one line that is never executed.

Hope this helps to understand the problem

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <fstream> // to read and write files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define n  200
using namespace std;

int global_totalNumberBlock = 0;
int global_totalNumberGrain = 0;

//tell the compiler that those classes exist
class Vec3d2;
class Block;
class Grain;
class Contact;
class Analysis;

class Vec3d2
{
public:
    __host__ __device__ Vec3d2(void);
    __host__ __device__ Vec3d2(double x_value, double y_value, double z_value);
    __host__ __device__ ~Vec3d2(void);
    __host__ __device__ double dot(Vec3d2 a) const;
    __host__ __device__ Vec3d2 cross(Vec3d2 a) const;
    __host__ __device__ double norm() const;
    __host__ __device__ void normalize();
    // to be able to use cout easily
    __host__ __device__ friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &s,const Vec3d2 &vec) 
    { 
        s << vec.x << endl;
        s << vec.y << endl;
        s << vec.z << endl;
        return s; 
    } 
    //to be able to use brackets
    __host__ __device__ double operator [](int i) const 
    {
        if( i == 0)
        {
            return x;
        }
        else if( i == 1)
        {
            return y;
        }
        else if( i == 2)
        {
            return z;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "ERROR IN USING VEC3D2" << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }
    __host__ __device__ double & operator [](int i) 
    {
        if( i == 0)
        {
            return x;
        }
        else if( i == 1)
        {
            return y;
        }
        else if( i == 2)
        {
            return z;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "ERROR IN USING VEC3D2" << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }

    //attributes
    double x, y, z;
};

//Class Vec3d2 functions and operators
Vec3d2::Vec3d2()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
}
Vec3d2::Vec3d2(double x_value, double y_value, double z_value)
{
    x =  x_value;
    y =  y_value;
    z =  z_value;
}
Vec3d2::~Vec3d2()
{
}
double Vec3d2::dot(Vec3d2 a) const
{
    return x*a.x + y*a.y + z*a.z;
}
Vec3d2 Vec3d2::cross(Vec3d2 a) const
{
    Vec3d2 result( y*a.z - z*a.y, x*a.z - z*a.x, x*a.y - y*a.x);
    return result;
}
double Vec3d2::norm() const
{
    return sqrt((double) x*x + y*y + z*z);
}
void Vec3d2::normalize()
{
    double norm = this->norm();
    if (norm > 0)
    {
        x = x/norm;
        y = y/norm;
        z = z/norm;
    }
    else //the vector has a null norm so nothing to do
    {
    }
}
__host__ __device__ Vec3d2 operator+(Vec3d2 const& a, Vec3d2 const& b)
{
    return Vec3d2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
}
__host__ __device__ Vec3d2 operator-(Vec3d2 const& a, Vec3d2 const& b)
{
    return Vec3d2(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
}
__host__ __device__ Vec3d2 operator*(Vec3d2 const& a, double const& b)
{
    return Vec3d2(b*a.x, b*a.y, b*a.z);
}
__host__ __device__ Vec3d2 operator*(double const& b, Vec3d2 const& a)
{
    return Vec3d2(b*a.x, b*a.y, b*a.z);
}
__host__ __device__ Vec3d2 operator/(Vec3d2 const& a, double const& b)
{
    return Vec3d2(a.x/b, a.y/b, a.z/b);
}
__host__ __device__ Vec3d2 operator/(double const& b, Vec3d2 const& a)
{
    return Vec3d2(a.x/b, a.y/b, a.z/b);
}
__host__ __device__ bool operator==(Vec3d2 const& a, Vec3d2 const& b)
{
    if(a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z == b.z)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
__host__ __device__ bool operator!=(Vec3d2 const& a, Vec3d2 const& b)
{
    if( a.x != b.x || a.y != b.y || a.z != b.z)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class Contact
{
public:
     __host__ __device__ Contact(void);
     //__host__ __device__ Contact(Contact const& ContactToCopy);
     __host__ __device__ ~Contact(void);
     __host__ __device__ void setContact(Grain &grain1, Grain &grain2, double overlap_value);
};

class Block
{
public:
     __host__ Block(void);
     __host__ Block(Block const& BlockToCopy);
     __host__ __device__ ~Block(void);

     __host__ __device__ Contact* getContactList() const;
     __host__ __device__ Contact** getContactListPtr();
     __host__ __device__ int getMaxNumberContact() const;
     __host__ __device__ int getNumberContact() const;

     __host__ __device__ void setContactList(Contact *ptr);
     __host__ __device__ void addContact(Contact contact_value);
     __host__ __device__ void clearContactList();// empty the contactList
     __host__ __device__ void deleteBlockData(); //clear the memory taken by the contactList
     __host__ __device__ Block& operator=(Block const& BlockToCopy);

protected:
    int Id; //unique Id number for each entity  double mass;

    int totalNumberBlock; //same value for each block, cannot use static attribute because of cuda
    Contact *contactList;
    int numberContact, old_numberContact; //because there is no way to find it from the pointer contactList
    int maxNumberContact; //maximum number of contact per block, we have to choose this
};

class Grain: public Block
{
public:
     __host__ Grain(void);
     __host__ Grain(Grain const& grainToCopy);
     __host__ Grain(Vec3d2 position_value, double radius_value, double mass_value);
     __host__ __device__ ~Grain(void);

     __host__ __device__ Vec3d2 getPositionVec() const;
     __host__ __device__ Vec3d2* getPosition() const;
     __host__ __device__ Vec3d2** getPositionPtr();
     __host__ __device__ int getTotalNumberGrain() const;

     __host__ void setTotalNumberGrain();
     __host__ __device__ void setTotalNumberGrain(int number);
     __host__ __device__ void setPosition(Vec3d2 *ptr);
     __host__ __device__ void setPositionVec(Vec3d2 position_value);
     __host__ __device__ void deleteGrainData();

     __host__ __device__ void findContactwithGrain(Grain *grainList);

     __host__ __device__ Grain& operator=(Grain const& grainToCopy);
     __host__ __device__ friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &s,const Grain &grain) 
     { 
         s <<"position is" << endl;
         s << *grain.position << endl;
         s <<"grain number is" << endl;
         s << grain.number << endl;
         s <<"radius is" << endl;
         s << grain.radius << endl;
         s <<"mass is" << endl;
         return s; 
     } 
private:
    Vec3d2 *position;

    int totalNumberGrain;
    int number; //different from Id defined in class Block because a wall could have the same number as a grain
    double radius;
};

class Analysis
{
public:
    Analysis(void);
    Analysis(Grain *grainList);
    ~Analysis(void);
    Grain* getGrainList();
    void copyToDevice();
    void copyToHost();
    void runAnalysis();
private: 
    //should contain grainList, wallList and their equivalent for the device
    //should contain an array of pointers for each attribute being a pointer in grain and wall and their equivalent in the device
    int totalNumberGrain, totalNumberWall;

    Grain *grainList, *d_grainList;

    //for grain data
    Contact **grain_contactList, **d_grain_contactList;
    Vec3d2 **grain_position, **d_grain_position;
};

//class Contact functions
Contact::Contact(void)
{
}
Contact::~Contact(void)
{
}
void Contact::setContact(Grain &grain1, Grain &grain2, double overlap_value)//we are in grain1 and contact with grain2
{
}

//class Block functions
Block::Block(void)
{
    Id = global_totalNumberBlock;
    numberContact = 0;
    old_numberContact = 0;
    //contact list settings
    maxNumberContact = 30;
    contactList = new Contact[maxNumberContact];
    //increment of block number
    global_totalNumberBlock = global_totalNumberBlock + 1;
}
Block::~Block(void)
{
    delete[] contactList;

    //cout << "CAREFUL, YOU ARE DESTROYING A BLOCK" << endl;//because we should never erase a block
    //system("PAUSE");
    totalNumberBlock = totalNumberBlock - 1;
}
Block::Block(Block const& BlockToCopy)
{
    Id = BlockToCopy.Id;

    numberContact = BlockToCopy.numberContact;
    old_numberContact = BlockToCopy.old_numberContact;
    maxNumberContact = BlockToCopy.maxNumberContact;

    contactList = new Contact[maxNumberContact];

    for(int i =0; i <numberContact; i++)
    {
        contactList[i] = BlockToCopy.contactList[i];
    }

}

Contact* Block::getContactList() const
{
    return contactList;
}
Contact** Block::getContactListPtr()
{
    return &contactList;
}
int Block::getMaxNumberContact() const
{
    return maxNumberContact;
}
int Block::getNumberContact() const
{
    return numberContact;
}
void Block::setContactList(Contact *ptr)
{
    //no "delete contactList" here because this is executed after cuda. The contactList is pointing to nothing and deleteing it will cause an error
    contactList = ptr;
}

void Block::addContact(Contact contact_value)
{
    if(numberContact < maxNumberContact)
    {
        contactList[numberContact] = contact_value;
        numberContact = numberContact + 1;
    }
    else //find a way to throw an error because the list is too small for all the contacts
    {
        printf("TOO MANY CONTACTS ON ONE GRAIN");
    }
}
void Block::clearContactList()
{
    //delete[] contactList;
    //contactList = new Contact[maxNumberContact];
    if(numberContact > 0)
    {
        numberContact = 0;
    }
}
void Block::deleteBlockData()
{
    delete[] contactList;
}

__host__ __device__ Block& Block::operator=(Block const& BlockToCopy)
{
    if(this != &BlockToCopy) //to check we are not doing a = a
    {
        Id = BlockToCopy.Id;

        numberContact = BlockToCopy.numberContact;
        old_numberContact = BlockToCopy.old_numberContact;
        maxNumberContact = BlockToCopy.maxNumberContact;

        delete[] contactList;

        contactList = new Contact[maxNumberContact];

        for(int i =0; i <numberContact; i++)
        {
            contactList[i] = BlockToCopy.contactList[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

//class Grain functions
Grain::Grain(void)
{
    number = global_totalNumberGrain;
    global_totalNumberGrain = global_totalNumberGrain + 1;
    totalNumberGrain = -1;//safety
    //initialize Vec3d2
    position = new Vec3d2;
}
Grain::Grain(Grain const& grainToCopy)
{
    cout <<"COPY CONSTRUCTOR OF GRAIN IS NOT DONE YET"<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    //totalNumberGrain = grainToCopy.totalNumberGrain;
    //radius = grainToCopy.radius;
    //diameter = grainToCopy.diameter;
    //volume = grainToCopy.volume;
    //inertia = grainToCopy.inertia;

    //position = new Vec3d2;
    //old_position = new Vec3d2;
    //old_velocity = new Vec3d2;
    //old_acceleration = new Vec3d2;
    //old_angularVelocity = new Vec3d2;
    //old_angularAcceleration = new Vec3d2;
    //gravityForce = new Vec3d2;

    //*position = *grainToCopy.position;
    //*old_position = *grainToCopy.old_position;
    //*old_velocity = *grainToCopy.old_velocity;
    //*old_acceleration = *grainToCopy.old_acceleration;
    //*old_angularVelocity = *grainToCopy.old_angularVelocity;
    //*old_angularAcceleration = *grainToCopy.old_angularAcceleration;
    //*gravityForce = *grainToCopy.gravityForce;
}
Grain::Grain(Vec3d2 position_value, double radius_value,double mass_value)//, number(totalNumberGrain)
{
    number = global_totalNumberGrain;
    global_totalNumberGrain = global_totalNumberGrain + 1;
    totalNumberGrain = -1;//safety
    radius = radius_value;
    //initialize all the Vec3d2 parameters
    position = new Vec3d2;

    *position = position_value;

}
Grain::~Grain(void)
{
    //cout << "CAREFUL, YOU ARE DESTROYING A GRAIN" << endl;//because we should never erase a block
    //system("PAUSE");
    totalNumberGrain = totalNumberGrain - 1;

    delete position;

}
Vec3d2 Grain::getPositionVec() const
{
    return *position;
}
Vec3d2* Grain::getPosition() const
{
    return position;
}
Vec3d2** Grain::getPositionPtr()
{
    return &position;
}
int Grain::getTotalNumberGrain() const
{
    return totalNumberGrain;
}
void Grain::setTotalNumberGrain()
{
    totalNumberGrain = global_totalNumberGrain;
}
void Grain::setTotalNumberGrain(int number)
{
    totalNumberGrain = number;
}
void Grain::setPosition(Vec3d2 *ptr)
{
    position = ptr;
}
void Grain::setPositionVec(Vec3d2 position_value)
{
    *position = position_value;
}
void Grain::deleteGrainData()
{
    delete position;
}
void Grain::findContactwithGrain(Grain *grainList)
{
    for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
    {
        double length;
        length = (*position - (*grainList[m].position)).norm();
        if( length < radius + grainList[m].radius)
        {
            if( number != grainList[m].number) //faster than number != sortedGrainList[m]
            {
                Vec3d2 relativePosition = *position - (*grainList[m].position) ;
                double overlap = radius + grainList[m].radius - relativePosition.norm();

                //define the contact
                Contact grainContact;           
                grainContact.setContact(*this, grainList[m], overlap);
                addContact(grainContact); //IF YOU PUT THIS LINE IN COMMENT, EVERYTHING GOES A LOT FASTER
            }
        }
    }
}
__host__ __device__ Grain& Grain::operator=(Grain const& grainToCopy)
{
    if(this != &grainToCopy)
    {
        Block::operator=(grainToCopy); //this lines call the operator = defined for Block. So it copies the block attributes of the first grain into the second grain

        //totalNumberGrain = grainToCopy.totalNumberGrain;
        radius = grainToCopy.radius;

        *position = *grainToCopy.position;
    }
    return *this;
}

//class Analysis functions
Analysis::Analysis(void)
{
}
Analysis::Analysis(Grain *grainList_value)
{
    totalNumberGrain = grainList_value[0].getTotalNumberGrain();

    grainList = new Grain[totalNumberGrain];

    //copy grains
    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumberGrain; i++)
    {
        grainList[i] = grainList_value[i];
        grainList[i].setTotalNumberGrain(grainList_value[i].getTotalNumberGrain());
    }
}
Analysis::~Analysis(void)
{
    delete[] grainList;

    //a lot more delete should be made here
}
Grain* Analysis::getGrainList()
{
    return grainList;
}
void Analysis::copyToDevice()
{
    //declare device grainList and wallList and copy the values
    cudaMalloc(&d_grainList, totalNumberGrain*sizeof(Grain));

    cudaMemcpy(d_grainList, grainList, totalNumberGrain*sizeof(Grain), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    ////declare device list of pointer to pass pointer values of grain
    d_grain_contactList = new Contact*[totalNumberGrain];
    d_grain_position = new Vec3d2*[totalNumberGrain];

    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumberGrain; i++)
    {
        cudaMalloc(&d_grain_contactList[i], grainList[i].getMaxNumberContact()*sizeof(Contact));
        cudaMalloc(&d_grain_position[i], sizeof(Vec3d2));
    }

    //copy pointers and values for grains
    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumberGrain; i++)
    {
        //pointers
        cudaMemcpy(d_grainList[i].getContactListPtr(), &d_grain_contactList[i], sizeof(Contact*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_grainList[i].getPositionPtr(), &d_grain_position[i], sizeof(Vec3d2*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        //values
        cudaMemcpy(d_grain_contactList[i], grainList[i].getContactList(), grainList[i].getMaxNumberContact()*sizeof(Contact), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_grain_position[i], grainList[i].getPosition(), sizeof(Vec3d2), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

}
void Analysis::copyToHost()
{
    //delete the pointer value or it will create a memory leak
    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumberGrain; i++)
    {
        grainList[i].deleteBlockData();
        grainList[i].deleteGrainData();
    }

    //copy non pointer value
    cudaMemcpy(grainList, d_grainList, totalNumberGrain*sizeof(Grain),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //copy pointer values for grains
    grain_contactList = new Contact*[totalNumberGrain];
    grain_position = new Vec3d2*[totalNumberGrain];

    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumberGrain; i++)
    {
        grain_contactList[i] = new Contact[grainList[i].getMaxNumberContact()];
        grain_position[i] = new Vec3d2;

        grainList[i].setContactList(grain_contactList[i]);
        grainList[i].setPosition(grain_position[i]);

        cudaMemcpy(grain_contactList[i], d_grain_contactList[i], grainList[i].getMaxNumberContact()*sizeof(Contact), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(grain_position[i], d_grain_position[i], sizeof(Vec3d2), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }
}

__global__ void compute( Grain *g)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    //__syncthreads();

    if( i < n )
    {   
        g[i].findContactwithGrain(g);
    }
}

void Analysis::runAnalysis()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    {
        clock_t begin = clock();
        for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            compute<<<(n + 511)/512, 512>>>(d_grainList);   
        }
        clock_t end = clock();

        cout << (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

        system("PAUSE");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    //grain
    Vec3d2 position1; position1[0] = 0;position1[1] = 0;position1[2] = 0;
    double radius1 = 1;

    ////cuda
    cout << "PRESS ENTER TO START" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    clock_t begin = clock();

    Grain *g, *d_g;
    g = new Grain[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        g[i].setTotalNumberGrain();
    }

    Grain g1(position1, radius1, 0.1);

    for(int i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        g[i] = g1;
        g[i].setPositionVec(Vec3d2(3*i+1.5, 1.5, 0));
    }

    Analysis a(g);
    a.copyToDevice();
    a.runAnalysis();

    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember, writing operations to global variables slow down a lot the code. Is `MyAttribute`been used anywhere else in the kernel? It can be that the compiler is detecting the write instruction and it's automatically adding synchronization mechanisms (like mutex).

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducable example

Comment: You could suffer from _aggressive compiler optimizations_, so a minimal reproducible example is mandatory.

Comment: My geuss would be, that this line prevents some compiler optimizations. The complexity of the condition would be especially interesting If you comment out the line and the condition evaluation has no side effects, the compiler is allowed to optimize the if statement away completely.

Comment: `clock()` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` are not accurate ways to measure wall clock time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861294/how-to-calculate-execution-time-of-a-code-snippet-in-c

Comment: I understand your desire to have nicely written object oriented code everywhere. However, in this circumstance I think it is adding a large overhead. I do believe it would be easier to optimize if you didn't send the entirety of the class to your kernels. It would make memory management issues easier to diagnose, of which I think you have quite a few.

Comment: @Christian I understand what you mean. The problem is this is only a sample of my code. As I said, my programing level is not so advanced and making more structure helps me both to correct "regular" bugs and keep my ideas clear in the 2000 lines of the program. In any case, there is nothing to do to fix my problem ?

Comment: I still concur with my answer below. I just suspect the code could be better optimized. I just think it would be difficult to do using large objects.

Comment: @Christian there are some things I don't understand. I added a printf after that line and it actually speeds up the time of execution... How could that be ? I also replaced the line by something like radius = 1 which is a global memory writing. This is also a lot faster than the original line, I suspect alignement of data is why this could be faster. But for that printf speeding up the execution, I really have no idea.

Comment: Change your timing method. Clock is not an accurate way to measure time. Use cuda events http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/

Answer (score 2):

I would need more code to verify but, the most likely explanation is that when you do not include code you are actually not writing any data to global memory. When you don't write anything to global memory nvcc will optimize just about everything out to the point where you will be running just about nothing.

The same is true when you include a print statement. Print statements are viewed as output, therefore nvcc can't compile out code that it is dependent on.

For example:

```
__global__ empty_kernel(int* huge_array, int num_elements){
    int local_memory;
    for(int i=0; i<num_elements; i++){
        local_memory+=huge_array[i];      
    }
}
```

will run faster than:

```
__global__ empty_kernel(int* small_array, int num_elements, int* smaller_array){
    int tid = ThreadIdx.x+BlockIdx.x*BlockDim.x;
    int local_memory;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        local_memory+=huge_array[tid*i];      
    }
    smaller_array[tid]=local_memory;
}
```

The bottom line being, your first kernel isn't faster, it just isn't being run.

Comment: I will try to add code that is able to run. But something in your answer is interesting: when I don't write to global memory, nvcc optimize it to run nothing. The thing is, in the if( condition seldom verified ), there is another line that I didn't write here. I define something like int myInt = computation base on Foo's attributes. As I define something, I think I write in global memory ? But this line does not slow down anything at all.

Comment: I added the code to my question. Hope this helps to find the problem.

Comment: With the code added to the question I think this answer is correct. If the stated line is removed, no global memory is written by the kernel, so the kernel does nothing, and is optimized away.

Comment: int myInt = computation does not write anything to global memory.  int myInt is a *local* memory variable.  I concur with Jez and Christian.  If you want more verification, dump the SASS code for the kernel in each case.  You'll find quite a difference. in the compiler generated code (`cuobjdump -sass myexe`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my opinion is simply the `if` statement, not the statement that it conditionally executes. Conditional branching can be quite expensive on GPU architectures (though it seems to get better with newer architectures), and just having a branching statement could definitely slow down your code.

If you remove the statement within the `if` clause, the compiler sees that no code is left and therefore can optimize also the `if` itself away. So this is why you see the speedup when you remove this line of code.