# How to save two camera's data but not influence their picture-acquire speed?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, buffer, avi

I am using a multispectral camera to collect data. One is near-infrared and another is colorful. Not two cameras, but one camera can obtain two different kinds of images in the same time. There are some API functions I could use like J_Image_OpenStream. Two part of core codes are shown as follows. One is used to open two streams(actually they are in one sample and I have to use them, but I am not too clearly with their meanings) and set the two avi files' saving paths and begin the acquisition.

```
 // Open stream
 retval0 = J_Image_OpenStream(m_hCam[0], 0, reinterpret_cast<J_IMG_CALLBACK_OBJECT>(this), reinterpret_cast<J_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION>(&COpenCVSample1Dlg::StreamCBFunc0), &m_hThread[0], (ViewSize0.cx*ViewSize0.cy*bpp0)/8);
if (retval0 != J_ST_SUCCESS) {
    AfxMessageBox(CString("Could not open stream0!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return;
}
TRACE("Opening stream0 succeeded\n");
retval1 = J_Image_OpenStream(m_hCam[1], 0, reinterpret_cast<J_IMG_CALLBACK_OBJECT>(this), reinterpret_cast<J_IMG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION>(&COpenCVSample1Dlg::StreamCBFunc1), &m_hThread[1], (ViewSize1.cx*ViewSize1.cy*bpp1)/8);
if (retval1 != J_ST_SUCCESS) {
    AfxMessageBox(CString("Could not open stream1!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return;
}
TRACE("Opening stream1 succeeded\n");

const char *filename0 = "C:\\Users\\shenyang\\Desktop\\test0.avi"; 
const char *filename1 = "C:\\Users\\shenyang\\Desktop\\test1.avi";
int fps = 10; //frame per second
int codec = -1;//choose the compression method

writer0 = cvCreateVideoWriter(filename0, codec, fps, CvSize(1296,966), 1);
writer1 = cvCreateVideoWriter(filename1, codec, fps, CvSize(1296,964), 1);

// Start Acquision
retval0 = J_Camera_ExecuteCommand(m_hCam[0], NODE_NAME_ACQSTART);
retval1 = J_Camera_ExecuteCommand(m_hCam[1], NODE_NAME_ACQSTART);


// Create two OpenCV named Windows used for displaying "BGR" and "INFRARED" images
cvNamedWindow("BGR");
cvNamedWindow("INFRARED");
```

Another one is the two stream functions, they look very similar.

```
void COpenCVSample1Dlg::StreamCBFunc0(J_tIMAGE_INFO * pAqImageInfo)
{
if (m_pImg0 == NULL)
{
    // Create the Image:
    // We assume this is a 8-bit monochrome image in this sample
    m_pImg0 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(pAqImageInfo->iSizeX, pAqImageInfo->iSizeY), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
}

// Copy the data from the Acquisition engine image buffer into the OpenCV Image obejct
memcpy(m_pImg0->imageData, pAqImageInfo->pImageBuffer, m_pImg0->imageSize);

// Display in the "BGR" window
cvShowImage("INFRARED", m_pImg0);

frame0 = m_pImg0;
cvWriteFrame(writer0, frame0);

}

void COpenCVSample1Dlg::StreamCBFunc1(J_tIMAGE_INFO * pAqImageInfo)
{
if (m_pImg1 == NULL)
{
    // Create the Image:
    // We assume this is a 8-bit monochrome image in this sample
    m_pImg1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(pAqImageInfo->iSizeX, pAqImageInfo->iSizeY), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
}

// Copy the data from the Acquisition engine image buffer into the OpenCV Image obejct
memcpy(m_pImg1->imageData, pAqImageInfo->pImageBuffer, m_pImg1->imageSize);

// Display in the "BGR" window
cvShowImage("BGR", m_pImg1);

frame1 = m_pImg1;
cvWriteFrame(writer1, frame1);
}
```

The question is if I do not save the avi files, as

```
/*writer0 = cvCreateVideoWriter(filename0, codec, fps, CvSize(1296,966), 1);
writer1 = cvCreateVideoWriter(filename1, codec, fps, CvSize(1296,964), 1);*/
//cvWriteFrame(writer0, frame0);
//cvWriteFrame(writer0, frame0);
```

In the two display windows, the pictures captured like similarly which means they are synchronous. But if I have to write data to the avi files, due to the different size of two kinds of pictures and their large size, it turns out that this influence the two camera's acquire speed and pictures captured are non-synchronous. But I could not create such a huge buffer to store the whole data in the memory and the I/O device is rather slow. What should I do? Thank you very very much.

some class variables are:

```
 public:
FACTORY_HANDLE  m_hFactory;             // Factory Handle
CAM_HANDLE      m_hCam[MAX_CAMERAS];    // Camera Handles
THRD_HANDLE     m_hThread[MAX_CAMERAS]; // Stream handles
char            m_sCameraId[MAX_CAMERAS][J_CAMERA_ID_SIZE]; // Camera IDs

IplImage        *m_pImg0 = NULL;        // OpenCV Images
IplImage        *m_pImg1 = NULL;        // OpenCV Images

CvVideoWriter* writer0;
IplImage *frame0;
CvVideoWriter* writer1;
IplImage *frame1;

BOOL OpenFactoryAndCamera();
void CloseFactoryAndCamera();
void StreamCBFunc0(J_tIMAGE_INFO * pAqImageInfo);
void StreamCBFunc1(J_tIMAGE_INFO * pAqImageInfo);
void InitializeControls();
void EnableControls(BOOL bIsCameraReady, BOOL bIsImageAcquiring);
```

Comment: The saving (and in fact any processing) should be done in a different thread that the capture -- i.e. the thread responsible for capturing the images from the camera shouldn't have any other responsibilities, just grab a frame and put it in some queue. You mention the I/O device is rather slow -- is it actually fast enough to handle the overall data rate?

Comment: I mean the time writing the data to the disk is much bigger then to the memory. Yes, I know saving will influence the capture speed. Do you mean I should create a queue or something else so that I could firstly put the data into it, and then use another function to write the data from the queue to the disk?

Comment: Thank you sincerely, I will try it.

Comment: Yes, a synchronized queue. You already make a copy from the capture buffer to OpenCV images, so just insert those into the queue. You may actually want to start using the C++ API (i.e. cv::VideoWriter, cv::Mat, etc.) rather than the obsolete C api you use currently. This will make the capturing independent of the saving. Periodically check the size of the queue, to avoid running out of memory. Also, you seem to have `int codec = -1;` as the FOURCC code for the video writer. What is the intent? What actual codec does that select?

Comment: Also, drop the `cvShowImage` from the capture loop (that takes a noticeable amount of time too), and add some [timing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861294/how-to-calculate-execution-time-of-a-code-snippet-in-c) to your code, so you have a better idea what's slowing it down, and how much. I'll see if I can write you a simple example on how this could be done.

Comment: Ok, I will finally drop the imshow code. Codec is the parameter used in windows operation system which means you can manually choose the system's codecs.

Comment: Yeah, meanwhile I've realized that the -1 is there in place of `CV_FOURCC_PROMPT`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct approach at recording the video without frame drops is to isolate the two tasks (frame acquisition, and frame serialization) such that they don't influence each other (specifically so that fluctuations in serialization don't eat away time from capturing the frames, which has to happen without delays to prevent frame loss).

This can be achieved by delegating the serialization (encoding of the frames and writing them into a video file) to separate threads, and using some kind of synchronized queue to feed the data to the worker threads.

Following is a simple example showing how this could be done. Since I only have one camera and not the kind you have, I will simply use a webcam and duplicate the frames, but the general principle applies to your scenario as well.

---

## Sample Code

In the beginning we have some includes:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
// ============================================================================
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::microseconds;
// ============================================================================
```

---

### Synchronized Queue

The first step is to define our synchronized queue, which we will use to communicate with the worker threads that write the video.

The primary functions we need is the ability to:

- Push new images into a the queue
- Pop images from the queue, waiting when it's empty.
- Ability to cancel all pending pops, when we're finished.

We use [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) to hold the [`cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#gsc.tab=0) instances, and [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to provide synchronization. A [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is used to notify the consumer when image has been inserted into the queue (or the cancellation flag set), and a simple boolean flag is used to notify cancellation.

Finally, we use the empty `struct cancelled` as an exception thrown from `pop()`, so we can cleanly terminate the worker by cancelling the queue.

```
// ============================================================================
class frame_queue
{
public:
    struct cancelled {};

public:
    frame_queue();

    void push(cv::Mat const& image);
    cv::Mat pop();

    void cancel();

private:
    std::queue<cv::Mat> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_;
    bool cancelled_;
};
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
frame_queue::frame_queue()
    : cancelled_(false)
{
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frame_queue::cancel()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
    cancelled_ = true;
    cond_.notify_all();
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void frame_queue::push(cv::Mat const& image)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
    queue_.push(image);
    cond_.notify_one();
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
cv::Mat frame_queue::pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);

    while (queue_.empty()) {
        if (cancelled_) {
            throw cancelled();
        }
        cond_.wait(mlock);
        if (cancelled_) {
            throw cancelled();
        }
    }

    cv::Mat image(queue_.front());
    queue_.pop();
    return image;
}
// ============================================================================
```

---

### Storage Worker

The next step is to define a simple `storage_worker`, which will be responsible for taking the frames from the synchronized queue, and encode them into a video file until the queue has been cancelled.

I've added simple timing, so we have some idea about how much time is spent encoding the frames, as well as simple logging to console, so we have some idea about what is happening in the program.

```
// ============================================================================
class storage_worker
{
public:
    storage_worker(frame_queue& queue
        , int32_t id
        , std::string const& file_name
        , int32_t fourcc
        , double fps
        , cv::Size frame_size
        , bool is_color = true);

    void run();

    double total_time_ms() const { return total_time_ / 1000.0; }

private:
    frame_queue& queue_;

    int32_t id_;

    std::string file_name_;
    int32_t fourcc_;
    double fps_;
    cv::Size frame_size_;
    bool is_color_;

    double total_time_;
};
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
storage_worker::storage_worker(frame_queue& queue
    , int32_t id
    , std::string const& file_name
    , int32_t fourcc
    , double fps
    , cv::Size frame_size
    , bool is_color)
    : queue_(queue)
    , id_(id)
    , file_name_(file_name)
    , fourcc_(fourcc)
    , fps_(fps)
    , frame_size_(frame_size)
    , is_color_(is_color)
    , total_time_(0.0)
{
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void storage_worker::run()
{
    cv::VideoWriter writer(file_name_, fourcc_, fps_, frame_size_, is_color_);

    try {
        int32_t frame_count(0);
        for (;;) {
            cv::Mat image(queue_.pop());
            if (!image.empty()) {
                high_resolution_clock::time_point t1(high_resolution_clock::now());

                ++frame_count;
                writer.write(image);

                high_resolution_clock::time_point t2(high_resolution_clock::now());
                double dt_us(static_cast<double>(duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()));
                total_time_ += dt_us;

                std::cout << "Worker " << id_ << " stored image #" << frame_count
                    << " in " << (dt_us / 1000.0) << " ms" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    } catch (frame_queue::cancelled& /*e*/) {
        // Nothing more to process, we're done
        std::cout << "Queue " << id_ << " cancelled, worker finished." << std::endl;
    }
}
// ============================================================================
```

---

### Processing

Finally, we can put this all together.

We begin by initializing and configuring our video source. Then we create two `frame_queue` instances, one for each stream of images. We follow this by creating two instances of `storage_worker`, one for each queue. To keep things interesting, I've set a different codec for each.

Next step is to create and start worker threads, which will execute the `run()` method of each `storage_worker`. Having our consumers ready, we can start capturing frames from the camera, and feed them to the `frame_queue` instances. As mentioned above, I have only single source, so I insert copies of the same frame into both queues.

**NB:** I need to use the `clone()` method of `cv::Mat` to do a deep copy, otherwise I would be inserting references to the single buffer OpenCV `VideoCapture` uses for performance reasons. That would mean that the worker threads would be getting references to this single image, and there would be no synchronization for access to this shared image buffer. You need to make sure this does not happen in your scenario as well.

Once we have read the appropriate number of frames (you can implement any other kind of stop-condition you desire), we cancel the work queues, and wait for the worker threads to complete.

Finally we write some statistics about the time required for the different tasks.

```
// ============================================================================
int main()
{
    // The video source -- for me this is a webcam, you use your specific camera API instead
    // I only have one camera, so I will just duplicate the frames to simulate your scenario
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);

    // Let's make it decent sized, since my camera defaults to 640x480
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 20.0);

    // And fetch the actual values, so we can create our video correctly
    int32_t frame_width(static_cast<int32_t>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)));
    int32_t frame_height(static_cast<int32_t>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));
    double video_fps(std::max(10.0, capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS))); // Some default in case it's 0

    std::cout << "Capturing images (" << frame_width << "x" << frame_height
        << ") at " << video_fps << " FPS." << std::endl;

    // The synchronized queues, one per video source/storage worker pair
    std::vector<frame_queue> queue(2);

    // Let's create our storage workers -- let's have two, to simulate your scenario
    // and to keep it interesting, have each one write a different format
    std::vector <storage_worker> storage;
    storage.emplace_back(std::ref(queue[0]), 0
        , std::string("foo_0.avi")
        , CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V')
        , video_fps
        , cv::Size(frame_width, frame_height)
        , true);

    storage.emplace_back(std::ref(queue[1]), 1
        , std::string("foo_1.avi")
        , CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')
        , video_fps
        , cv::Size(frame_width, frame_height)
        , true);

    // And start the worker threads for each storage worker
    std::vector<std::thread> storage_thread;
    for (auto& s : storage) {
        storage_thread.emplace_back(&storage_worker::run, &s);
    }

    // Now the main capture loop
    int32_t const MAX_FRAME_COUNT(10);
    double total_read_time(0.0);
    int32_t frame_count(0);
    for (; frame_count < MAX_FRAME_COUNT; ++frame_count) {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1(high_resolution_clock::now());

        // Try to read a frame
        cv::Mat image;
        if (!capture.read(image)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to capture image.\n";
            break;
        }

        // Insert a copy into all queues
        for (auto& q : queue) {
            q.push(image.clone());
        }        

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2(high_resolution_clock::now());
        double dt_us(static_cast<double>(duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()));
        total_read_time += dt_us;

        std::cout << "Captured image #" << frame_count << " in "
            << (dt_us / 1000.0) << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

    // We're done reading, cancel all the queues
    for (auto& q : queue) {
        q.cancel();
    }

    // And join all the worker threads, waiting for them to finish
    for (auto& st : storage_thread) {
        st.join();
    }

    if (frame_count == 0) {
        std::cerr << "No frames captured.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    // Report the timings
    total_read_time /= 1000.0;
    double total_write_time_a(storage[0].total_time_ms());
    double total_write_time_b(storage[1].total_time_ms());

    std::cout << "Completed processing " << frame_count << " images:\n"
        << "  average capture time = " << (total_read_time / frame_count) << " ms\n"
        << "  average write time A = " << (total_write_time_a / frame_count) << " ms\n"
        << "  average write time B = " << (total_write_time_b / frame_count) << " ms\n";

    return 0;
}
// ============================================================================
```

---

## Console Output

Running this little sample, we get the following log output in the console, as well as the two video files on the disk.

**NB:** Since this was actually encoding a lot faster than capturing, I've added some wait into the storage_worker to show the separation better.

```
Capturing images (1920x1080) at 20 FPS.
Captured image #0 in 111.009 ms
Captured image #1 in 67.066 ms
Worker 0 stored image #1 in 94.087 ms
Captured image #2 in 62.059 ms
Worker 1 stored image #1 in 193.186 ms
Captured image #3 in 60.059 ms
Worker 0 stored image #2 in 100.097 ms
Captured image #4 in 78.075 ms
Worker 0 stored image #3 in 87.085 ms
Captured image #5 in 62.061 ms
Worker 0 stored image #4 in 95.092 ms
Worker 1 stored image #2 in 193.187 ms
Captured image #6 in 75.074 ms
Worker 0 stored image #5 in 95.093 ms
Captured image #7 in 63.061 ms
Captured image #8 in 64.061 ms
Worker 0 stored image #6 in 102.098 ms
Worker 1 stored image #3 in 201.195 ms
Captured image #9 in 76.074 ms
Worker 0 stored image #7 in 90.089 ms
Worker 0 stored image #8 in 91.087 ms
Worker 1 stored image #4 in 185.18 ms
Worker 0 stored image #9 in 82.08 ms
Worker 0 stored image #10 in 94.092 ms
Queue 0 cancelled, worker finished.
Worker 1 stored image #5 in 179.174 ms
Worker 1 stored image #6 in 106.102 ms
Worker 1 stored image #7 in 105.104 ms
Worker 1 stored image #8 in 103.101 ms
Worker 1 stored image #9 in 104.102 ms
Worker 1 stored image #10 in 104.1 ms
Queue 1 cancelled, worker finished.
Completed processing 10 images:
  average capture time = 71.8599 ms
  average write time A = 93.09 ms
  average write time B = 147.443 ms
  average write time B = 176.673 ms
```

---

## Possible Improvements

Currently there is no protection against the queue getting too full in the situation when the serialization simply can't keep up with the rate the camera generates new images. Set some upper limit for the queue size, and check in the producer before you push the frame. You will need to decide how exactly you want to handle this situation.

Comment: Thank you again! I have tried one day to adjust my codes. Due to my bad coding habit, like using the namespace std, so the variable queue defined by "std::vector<frame_queue> queue(2)" will cause uncertainty in mine. Now I learn the importance of using std:: but not namespace.

Comment: But there is still one problem. By using the MAX_FRAME_COUNT, we can control the memory usage, however, if we need to do the real-time video recording, it happens that the memory is not enough to hold the all image data and the system will stop it before the real end.

Comment: So the writing or encoding is still too slow to keep up, even with the least demanding codec? (I assume this is not case of you running out of disk space). No chance to add memory or use more performant system, I presume? Let me guess, is it [this camera](http://www.jai.com/en/products/ad-130ge)? Two 8bit 1 channel images (the Bayer colour and IR) at 1296x966 and 31 FPS -> `1.2MiB * 2 * 31 Hz = 74.4 MiB/s`. Can your storage handle such sustained rate? Make a test and measure it. And instead of VideoWriter, try just dumping the raw frames into a binary file, that should have least overhead.

Comment: Yech, it is exactly the same camera. I have resized the image into 640*480 in order to save some time. I will try binary file and add some virtual memory. It is so nice of you to help me a lot  ^_^

Comment: You might also be able to set a ROI on the camera, if you don't need all of the image, and change the frame rate to a slower fixed rate. [Binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) might help too, by doing the resize for you, if available. Careful about manually resizing the [Bayer image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) -- if you just resize the single channel image, you will corrupt the colour information. You would need to either drop the colour info by interpolating to grayscale, or make it a 3 channel image, but that won't help much in terms of space requirements.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I will notice the resize.