# OpenCV threaded VideoCapture

Tags: multithreading, opencv, c++11

I'm working on a school project that requires the use of OpenCV. I've developed a lane detection algorithm for an RC car. The video capture on my laptop is just fine; however, I'd like to use a raspberry pi. I've built my program on the raspberry pi (release) and there is quite a bit of latency (1-2sec) and the framerate is not stellar. I'd like to try and implement a second thread for the video capture because, from what i understand, VideoCapture() is blocking. I was wondering if this is possible and if so, where should I look for resources to get it up and running?

Thanks!

BTW: I'm using c++ so I was thinking of using intel tbb or c++ thread

Comment: show your code please

Comment: You may get some inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37146523/3962537).