# webcam time inaccuracy, setting exposure time

Tags: c#, multithreading, graphics, directx, webcam

I have a complex problem, I've been working on it for weeks. My program is an eduactional software which use the webcam for analyzing physical experiments (eg. oscillating movement). I've experienced the folowings:

- If the processor is busy, the time
  measuring is inaccurate
  (ISampleGrabberCB.BufferCB(SampleTime))
- If I don't use the time, just count
  the samples: 0, 1, 2... it looks
  better. I perceive this when I look
  at the curve of the movement.

My primary goal is reduce the inaccuracy, what I try to achieve with limitation of the FPS (which cause busy processor).

- My WebCam (Intel Classmate PC's built
  in webcam) has auto fps and exposure
  time. Depending on the illumination
  they fluctuate.
- IAMStreamConfig.AvgTimePerFrame has no effect.
- IAMCameraControl isn't supported by the webcam.
- IKsPropertySet: I don't know how to
  use this, since I don't have any
  support for the webcam. In this
  example they can use it for Logitech
  webcam: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/47b1317d-87e6-4121-9189-0defe1e2dd44

Answer (score 1):

from the MSDN article on [Time and Clocks in DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924825.aspx):

> Any object that supports the IReferenceClock interface can serve as a reference clock. A filter with access to a hardware timer can provide a clock (an example is the audio renderer), or the filter graph manager can create one that uses the system time.

I've never attempted to use the IReferenceClock from a filter, but it would be my suspicion that it may not provide a high resolution clock that you need.

This [SO post on high resolution timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer) might be what you need.

IAMStreamConfig.AvgTimePerFrame is for informational purposes, and attempting to adjust it won't have any effect.  It's just a value from which you can calculate average frame rate for your video stream.

e.g.

```
VIDEOINFOHEADER* pVih = (VIDEOINFOHEADER*)m_MediaTypes.VideoType.pbFormat;

if( pVih )  
    int nFrameRate = (int)( (double) (10000000.0f / pVih->AvgTimePerFrame) );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried different high resulotion timers, but this doesn't solve my problem. I need the accurate time of the sample, and it isn't help if I know
the accurate time in an other moment. If I implement the IReferenceClock, and build it to my graph, it takes anything for me? (I think not, for the same reason)

IAMStreamConfig.AvgTimePerFrame: You can change the AvgTimePerFrame's value, and it works for me with other webcams, but not with this. I have to optimalize my program 
to Intel Classmate PC, so I have to work with this hardware.