# C++: More precise timing intervals

Tags: c++, timing

I need to periodically do a particular task and am currently using nanosleep.

The task needs to be run every second or every 10 seconds.

Is there a better way to do this than:

```
while(true)
{
 doTask();
 sleep();
}
```

Walter

Comment: It has nothing to do with C++, it's OS dependent. Isn't precision of `sleep` good enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Cross-Platform High-Resolution Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer)

Comment: My application isn't very stable - I don't see what's going on in the log file, but basically it should be saving a file every 10 seconds or so.  I let it run a few hours and see that it skipped over a bunch of files it was supposed to save.  How can I tell what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options could be to create a thread that will do the task with specified timeout.

Comment: Is that a better approach than sleeping?  Shouldn't they have the same resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thread library to create a thread which handle run the doTask(). Your main thread just keeps sleeping and runs every 1 second or 10 seconds.

This can be done with a QTimer and a QRunnable.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html

According to the dock, the resolution is around 1 ms in most cases. For your need, this should be sufficient.