# Boost timer - how to set level of detail, I want microseconds?

Tags: c++, boost, timer

So I try to create simple speed bench with boost 1.47.0. But results like 1.423 are not detailed enough for me. I need more detailed ones. How to get tham? How to make boost::timer show microseconds?

bench code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/progress.hpp>

class TestDs 
{
public:

    virtual bool containsKey(int key)=0;
    virtual int get(int key)=0;
    virtual int put(int key, int value)=0;
    virtual int remove(int key)=0;

    virtual int size()=0;
    virtual const char* name()=0;
    virtual void print()=0;
    virtual void shutdown()=0;
};

class GeneralMap: public TestDs
{
private:

    std::map<int,int> _ds;
    mutable boost::mutex mut_;
public:
    GeneralMap() {}

    bool containsKey(int key) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        if ( _ds.find(key) != _ds.end())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int get(int key) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        return _ds[key];
    }

    int put(int key, int value) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        _ds.insert(std::pair<int, int>(key,value));
        return key;
    }

    int remove(int key) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        return _ds.erase(key);
    }

    int size() {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        return _ds.size();
    }
    const char* name() {
        return "StdMap";
    }
    void print() {}
    void shutdown() {}

};


int n;
boost::shared_mutex  tests;
boost::shared_mutex  results;
boost::random::mt19937 rng;
boost::timer timerForCaptureFame;
GeneralMap Ds;
boost::progress_display *show_progress;

void test( int i)
{
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock_r(results);
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(tests);
    Ds.put(i, 0);
    if (Ds.containsKey(i))
    {
        Ds.get(i);
    }
    Ds.remove(i);
    ++(*show_progress);

}

void result()
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(results);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);

    std::cout <<  std::endl << "test of " << Ds.name() << " complite;" << std::endl << "test performed on " << n << " items" << std::endl << "test duration: " << timerForCaptureFame.elapsed() << std::endl;
}

void create_tests( int n)
{

    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(tests);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);

    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock_r(results);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> ran = boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<>(1, n*10);
        int x = ran(rng);
        boost::thread worker(test, x);
    }
    boost::thread worker_r(result);
    timerForCaptureFame.restart();
    return;
}



int main()
{
    n = 1000;
    show_progress = new boost::progress_display(n);
    create_tests(n);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this [thread](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2005/03/81582.php) from the Boost mailing page helps.
And you could look at this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer) question

Answer (score 2):

> How to make boost::timer show microseconds?

Boost's timer library is dependant on the C standard library clock() function and CLOCKS_PER_SEC. That maximum resolution you can get depends on that, so I would investigate that first to see if your system supports microsecond resolution.

MSVC is set to CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000 so you wouldn't be able to get microsecond resolution if that's what you are compiling with. Other systems do support CLOCKS_PER_SECOND == 1000000, so you should consider setting fixed output format and setting a precision for doubles:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::precision(6) << timerForCaptureFame.elapsed();
```