# C++ chrono: Get seconds with a precision of 3 decimal places

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

This might sound like a basic question but I've searched a lot. I am trying to **time-profile** a function call in `C++` & need to log the time in seconds up to `3 decimal places`. For example `2.304 seconds` or `.791 seconds`. I am trying to use `std::chrono` to do it like this:

```
auto start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
DoSomeOperation();
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start_time;
double execution_time = elapsed_time.count();

std::cout << "execution_time = " << execution_time << std::endl;
```

Following is the output I am getting:

```
execution_time = 1.9e-05
execution_time = 2.1e-05
execution_time = 1.8e-05
execution_time = 1.7e-05
```

I am sure that `DoSomeOperation` only takes a few `milliseconds` to complete & I need the number in `seconds`. I need the number in double to use it in a different calculation.

*How can I convert this weird `1.9e-05` into a sensible number in `double` which yields in seconds like `.304` or `.067` ?*

Trying the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391327/how-to-get-duration-as-int-millis-and-float-seconds-from-chrono), I've the same problem.

Comment: Move it a few magnitudes up. I recommend first checking, what time unit the method `now` returns, and do a conversion.

NOTE: I think it returns time in seconds, but I am not sure

Comment: `1.9e-05` is not weird. It means _multiply `1.9` by ten to the power `-5`_.

Comment: @ForceBru hehe. thanks for detailing that out.

Comment: So as the execution times are in microseconds you'll only get zeroes out of this in seconds in three decimals. But if you're trying some other code timings then it might show something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the output format, try [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

```
double execution_time = 0.01234;
std::cout << "execution_time = "
          << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3)
          << execution_time << std::endl;
```

If you have several places where you need to output the execution time, it can be converted to a string and then re-used:

```
double execution_time = 0.01234;
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << execution_time;
std::string execution_time_as_string = stream.str();

std::cout << "execution_time = " << execution_time_as_string << std::endl;
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to do the changes on `execution_time` before the `std::cout`. I need to use the variable `execution_time` in some other places in my program as well

Comment: @SegmentationFault Sorry, I did not understand. What I'm trying to say is that you just need proper formatting option to avoid scientific notation in the output.

Comment: Reducing the accuracy of the internal number is silly. Use whatever resolution it has, and round the result to milliseconds only for display. However if you must have milliseconds, then take the float value, multiply by 1000, and store it in an integer type as milliseconds.  Display as seconds by converting it where you must display as seconds.

Comment: @AlexD My question was that : How can apply `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision(3)` on `execution_time` without the `std::cout` ?

Comment: Oh, you mean how to round it up? It could be done with help of `round`, but it is better to keep the data and just change the way you output it, as **@KennyOstrom** mentioned.

Comment: @SegmentationFault Just added outputting to a string, you could re-use it in several places.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
cout.precision(3);
cout << MyDouble;
```