# C++, how do you scale a std::chrono::duration?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I do not understand how you are supposed to scale a `std::chrono::duration`. What is the correct way to scale a duration by a floating point number?

```
template <class Duration>
auto random_duration(Duration low, Duration high) noexcept -> Duration {
    static auto rd = std::random_device();
    static auto re = std::default_random_engine(rd());
    auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0, 1);
    const auto off = std::chrono::duration<Duration>(dist(re) * (high - low));
    return low + off;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have? You do scale the duration by a random factor, no?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 It doesn't compile.

Comment: A correct way of scaling a duration by a floating-point number is to "multiply" them by `std::chrono::duration::operator*` (see, e.g., https://wandbox.org/permlink/kWdtlyShNEjGAwSC). What is your problem? Please, provide a reproducible example. What is your error? What do you pass as a template argument?

Comment: please include the compiler error in the question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @lubgr It compiles for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xRvGJuSl5pAEkMxn.

Comment: Just remove the cast to `std::chrono::duration<Duration>` and you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Holt Doesn't that depend on the `Duration` type you pass in, i.e., it might work but could also fail?

Comment: @lubgr Sorry I did not see that OP wanted to return a `Duration`, which is very weird... If remove the `std::chrono::duration<Duration>` and the explicit return type, you'll get an automatic return type, which is probably what you want. Casting to `Duration` will lose a lot of precision, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Paul You want to scale by a floating point number and then "cast" to the original representation? E.g., `1.3 * (4s - 2s)` -> `2.6s` -> `2s`?

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [How to get duration, as int milli's and float seconds from <chrono>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14391327/580083).

Comment: Style guide 1:  This function is overly generic in its template parameter.  It accepts anything.  Templatize on `Rep` and `Period` and make the parameter `duration<Rep, Period>`.

Comment: Style guide 2:  This function needlessly restricts the two duration parameters to have the same units.  Let them be different:  `template <class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2> auto random_duration(duration<Rep1, Period1>, duration<Rep2, Period2>)`.

Comment: Style guide 3:  Let the function return the type that is the `common_type` of the two durations multiplied by a `double`.  This is most easily accomplished by deducing the return type (requires C++14).  This also implies loosing all casts within the implementation of the function.  The _client_ of this function can decide if he wants to change the type of the result to something else.  `template <class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2> auto random_duration(duration<Rep1, Period1>, duration<Rep2, Period2>) {...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you instantiate this template with two `std::duration<double, ...>` objects, everything works fine and as expected. The issue you encouter is probably that the instance you get by [`operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4) might not implicitly convertible to the trailing return type (`Duration`) when the input type is something like `std::duration<int, ...>`. In this case, scaling it by a double is a lossy operation, which (if you intend this) is fine on its own, but return it is as a `Duration` is *not*. `<chrono>` doesn't permit such a conversion unless you are explicit. This is a good thing.

Here is how it could work.

```
const auto off = dist(re)*((high - low));

return low + std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(off);
```

So you need to explicitly do the possibly lossy conversion of the input durations to one that can be multiplied by a `double`. Once you have that, in order to be compliant with the trailing return type `Duration`, you need to explicitly convert it back.

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds d1(10); auto d2 = 2.5 * d1;` This compiles for me despite that the `Rep` type for `seconds` is integral.

Comment: Cppreference says for `operator*`: _Converts the duration `d` to one whose `rep` is the **common type** between `Rep1` and `Rep2`, and multiples the number of ticks after conversion by `s`._

Comment: Ok, I get it know. The `auto d2` you get (wandbox link above) is a `std::duration<double>` because that's the result with the `common_type` template that determines the return type of `operator`. The OP's issue is that the return type as the _original_ representation, and that is a lossy conversion.