# How do I trigger a function at regular intervals during the run time

Tags: c++, timer, c++-chrono

I have a chrono timer setup to count up until 'x' amount of time.
So inside this while loop, how can I make the program trigger a function at specific intervals (e.g. every 1 min, every 2 sec, etc.)

```
const double LIMIT = 5.0 ;

int main(){

    cout << "-- Email Simulation --" << endl;

    Timer timer;   
    timer.start();



    while( timer.elapsedSeconds() < LIMIT ){
         // do stuff here
    }


    timer.stop();
    cout << "Elapsed Time : " << timer.elapsedSeconds() << "s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use this method but that triggers the function more than once which is not what I want.

```
if( timer.elapsedSeconds() == x ){
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)?

Comment: Hey it worked! thanks!

Comment: If you need the interval to really be regular, and not drift, use `sleep_until` instead of `sleep_for`.  Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50137677/576911