# software Interrupt Service routine in C for windows operating system

Tags: c, timer, operating-system, interrupt, clock

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

void Task()
{
    printf("Hi");
}

int main ( ) {
    time_t t;
    clock_t start, end;
    long i;
    long count;
    double x = 0.0;
    count = 2;

    start = clock();

    time(&t);

    printf(ctime(&t));
    printf( "Counting to %ld\n", count );

    if(count)
    {
        Task();
    }

    end = clock();

    printf( "That took %f seconds and I counted up to %ld", (((double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)), count );
    printf( "\nThat also took %d clock tics\n ", clock());
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get the start time and end time taken to execute the Task function. I am trying to create interrupt for the Task function but displaying Hi in the program. I am not successful with that. So could you please anyone can guide me regarding this.

Comment: There is no way of having interrupts in user-mode, only kernel-mode drivers can service interrupt requests. There's probably another solution (e.g., some kind of callback as the multimedia timers of Windows) but please expose your problem more in detail so that readers can exactly understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: Why would you want to create interrupt handler in Windows?

Comment: For every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. there should be call to a specific function!!! In the above I have just trying to do for 2ms!!!

Comment: Why do you want to call a function each 2 ms, etc.?

Comment: `if (2)` doesn't block your program for 2ms.

Comment: I have to call the Task function at 2ms!!! another example : have to call another task function at 10ms. How to do this ??

Comment: Sachin, you are only tell us what you want to do but you are not telling us why you want to do it and why do you think it is the right approach to solving your task.

Comment: There are three task and it should be called at different time.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with the [Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Another possible approach might be using [`CreateTimerQueueTimer()` and friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: How to calculate the start time and end time for the task ??

Comment: @sachins: Read the docs carefuly: `CreateTimerQueueTimer() - DueTime [in]` The amount of time in milliseconds _relative to the current time_ that must elapse before the timer is signaled for the first time.

Comment: could you please write me a code to calculate a start time and end time ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of having interrupts in user-mode, only kernel-mode drivers can service interrupt requests.

However you can have a callback function called by the OS in a periodic way. On Windows you can achieve this using the multimedia times (however declared obsolete by Microsoft) or timer queue timers (check this, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is an old test program I wrote that uses the Multimedia timers (obsolete but they still work on recent Windows versions...):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

volatile long timer = 0;

// Will be called every 1 ms
void CALLBACK timer_func(UINT uTimerID, UINT uMsg, DWORD *dwUser,
    DWORD *dw1, DWORD *dw2)
{
    timer++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MMRESULT id = timeSetEvent(1, 0, (LPTIMECALLBACK) timer_func, NULL, TIME_PERIODIC);
    printf("Waiting 10 seconds... ");
    fflush(stdout);
    Sleep(10000);
    printf("ok. Timer = %ld.\n", timer);
    timeKillEvent(id);
    return 0;
}
```

If you just want to precisely measure how long a function call lasts, just use QueryPerformanceCounter() and QueryPerformanceFrequency():

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void task()
{
    // do something...
}

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER start, stop, freq;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    task();
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

    double time_len = (stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double) freq.QuadPart;
    printf("Task length: %0.8f seconds.\n", time_len);
}
```

Comment: How to calculate the start time and end time for the task ??

Comment: I added an example of how to have a callback function called periodically (for instance every 1 ms in the example code). Then what you do inside the function depends on your application...

Comment: After the task(void CALLBACK timer_func(UINT uTimerID, UINT uMsg, DWORD *dwUser,DWORD *dw1, DWORD *dw2) in the above case starts executing. the body of the function could be anything!!! question : how to calculate start time of the process and end time of the process ??

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your question... what are you exactly trying to do? Measuring how much time something (your task?) lasts? But in this case, why do you need an "interrupt" function? Could you please explain more in detail what you are looking for?

Comment: how to calculate the timestamp ??

Comment: I will interrupt at specific time and later when the task starts executing, how to calculate the time of executing the task and end of execution. Timestamp = endtime - start time;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds?rq=1

Comment: can I use the above ideas from the link to calculate the time ??

Comment: Sure you can use for example QueryPerformanceCounter() and QueryPerformanceFrequency() to get very precise timing about how long a function is running. But I don't yet see what you want to do with your periodic "interrupt" function, and how it relates with the timing. If you just want to time a function, just call QueryPerformanceCounter() before and after, and then divide the difference by the value returned by QueryPerformanceCounter (casted to a double) to get the running time of your function in seconds.

Comment: Ale: I want to do that only. Could you please give me an example ??

Comment: I added an example of how to use those in my answer.

Comment: Ale : is it possible to calculate getstopwatch(); ??

Comment: what is getstopwatch()? what do you want this function to return, something like the elapsed time since a hypothetical startstopwatch()?

Comment: Ale: yes!! what you said is perfect.

Comment: In a function they mentioned somthing like :  1: uint32 startTime = GetStopwatch();  last line : duration10ms = (uint32)( ( GetStopwatch() - startTime ) / STOPWATCH_TICKS_PER_US ); // I am not able to put the full code here!!! could you tell me what is that ??

Comment: They? Do you have a link? It looks like code for a microcontroller more than for a PC... (although this does not mean that there's no way of doing the same on a PC)

Comment: can I have your email id ?? I'll send that code across you !!

Comment: you can send me a message on <1x2rl5gyovzyfx0@jetable.org> (valid only today)

Comment: Ok, received your code, actually this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638163/high-precision-event-timer. The GetStopWatch() function is doing, on its specific platform, exactly the same thing that QueryPerformanceCounter() does on Windows, the only differences being that it uses 32-bit integers instead of 64-bit, and that it gives the results in the return value rather than taking a pointer. The STOPWATCH_TICKS_PER_US would be basically equivalent to the value returned by QueryPerformanceFrequency() divided by 1000000 (as that function returns the number of ticks per second).

Comment: all the info needed about how to modify the example code should be in my previous comment... what else do you need to know?

Comment: Ale: The code sent to you is having a GetStopWatch() function. how to modify your code w.r.t. Could you PLEASE give me an example to modify your code to that ??

Comment: I cant modify the LARGE_INTEGER data type to any other data type uint64 then it will throw an error like : error C2224: left of Quadpart must have struct/union type.

Comment: Ale: could you please help me ??

Answer (score 0):

New answer after discussion (see comments of my previous answer): you can implement an equivalent to the GetStopWatch() function you want this way:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// assuming we return times with microsecond resolution
#define STOPWATCH_TICKS_PER_US  1

uint64_t GetStopWatch()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t, freq;
    uint64_t val;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    return (uint64_t) (t.QuadPart / (double) freq.QuadPart * 1000000);
}

void task()
{
    // do something...
}

int main()
{
  uint64_t start = GetStopWatch();
  task();
  uint64_t stop = GetStopWatch();

  printf("Elapsed time (microseconds): %lld\n", stop - start);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: #include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// assuming we return times with microsecond resolution
#define STOPWATCH_TICKS_PER_US  1

uint64_t GetStopWatch()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t, freq;
    uint64_t val;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    return (uint64_t) (t.QuadPart / (double) freq.QuadPart * 1000000);
}
task()
{
printf("hello\n");
}
int main()
{
  uint64_t start = GetStopWatch();
  task();
  uint64_t stop = GetStopWatch();
  printf("Elapsed time (microseconds): %lld\n", stop - start);
}

Comment: If I call the task() function multiple times and it is printing hello. The (stop- start) value is different for calling task function multiple times. I am not getting the same elapsed time for calling it.

Comment: This is normal, you could only assume constant timing for a function call if you're running it without any interrupts enabled (which is of course impossible on a multitasking OS as Windows, except if you run it inside a kernel driver). The time you see for your task() function call includes the time it takes to run the function itself, but also the time the system was running other processes or servicing interrupts.

Comment: I need your guidance.  If I want to get the same elapsed time then what should I do ??

Comment: There are three tasks  : task2, task10 and task100. I am using the create timer queue function to call the above three task from main function for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. Inside the void task2, void task10 and void task100()  : I am using Query performance counter to calculate the elapsed time (I am using your code). But I am getting the different elapsed time for the task running multiple times. (The tasks are just printing hi(void task2), hello (void task10), hheh(void task100)) . if void task2 function is called first and I should get the same elapsed time during run time.

Comment: Which elapsed time are you wanting to calculate? How long the single task() functions take? Or the time between them? Please be more clear in your questions, otherwise it's not possible to answer.

Comment: Elapsed time nothing but the stop-start time

Comment: Ok but what are your start and stop times? The start and stop of each single task?