# odd behaviour using chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I've been looking at various game timing loop methods e.g. Glenn Fiedler and DeWitter. I found critical areas difficult to understand due to my own C++ knowledge limitations. With this I set about trying to implement my own method....I thought a good way to try to understand something about these methods.

[edit1: I'm using CodeBlocks IDE with minGW-w64 (x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5) as the compiler]

[edit2: code and output windows amended to include a 3rd timer, QueryPerformanceCounter]

In trying to accomplish this I came across the following issue:

Minimal code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

LARGE_INTEGER startqpc, stopqpc, li;
double PCFreq = 0.0;


void print()
{
for (int p=0; p<1000000; ) p += 1;  //adjust till ms (steady) returns 1-2ms
}

int main()
{
    for(int x=0; x<200; x += 1)
    {
    steady_clock::time_point start = steady_clock::now();
    auto timePoint1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
        cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";
    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startqpc);

    print();

    steady_clock::time_point finish = steady_clock::now();
    auto timePoint2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stopqpc);
    auto elapsedTime(timePoint2 - timePoint1);
    double diff = (stopqpc.QuadPart - startqpc.QuadPart)/PCFreq;

    cout << "Elapsed time: "
              << duration_cast<milliseconds>(finish - start).count() << "ms (steady)   "
              << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<float, milli >> (elapsedTime).count() << "ms (hires)   "
              << diff << " (qpc) \n";

    }
}
```

For comparison purposes, the above code makes use of two timers.

On my PC the output from this is as follows:

```
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8429 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8429 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85152 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.85557 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.59283 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.25573 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85072 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85422 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.85099 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.31582 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.84964 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.52466 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   2.25169 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.26974 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84991 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84667 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.89518 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.87874 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.92213 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.87605 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.03126 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.87659 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.88467 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.24899 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.30316 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23579 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23552 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   2.42118 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.24522 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23471 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23848 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9329 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.85126 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.35355 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23687 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23633 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.2374 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23498 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85449 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.0097 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.15441 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23579 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   2.04554 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.1121 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.01779 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.07222 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9329 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.95015 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.95177 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84587 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85233 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.88278 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84667 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.88629 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.8588 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.06225 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23633 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93317 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.06009 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.86284 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.02803 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.26839 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93398 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.93641 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93371 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93344 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9329 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.02345 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.08731 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9356 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93398 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.09 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93371 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.03072 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.19213 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85287 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9321 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93344 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93317 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93344 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.42711 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.9418 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9356 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.08947 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9329 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93614 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   2.27702 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93614 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93317 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.08974 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.92698 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93317 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   2.09054 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.96066 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.96093 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.91835 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84587 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85233 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93317 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93317 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.23552 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.93102 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.07033 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.09405 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.9329 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.93263 (qpc)

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.484 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Using `duration_cast<microseconds>(finish - start).count()/1000.0` for the steady_clock we see the following:-

```
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.843ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84317 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.846ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84694 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.877ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.87685 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.916ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.9162 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.906ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.90623 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.905ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.90515 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.909ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.90919 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.905ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.90542 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.905ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.90488 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.943ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.94287 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.872ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.87281 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.846ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.8464 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.875ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.87497 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.033ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.03449 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.922ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.92293 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.922ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.92293 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.926ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.92698 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.004ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   2.00485 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.847ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84748 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.847ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84748 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.848ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84856 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.849ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84937 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.299ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.29938 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 3.497ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   3.49664 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 3.528ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   3.52843 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.299ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.29857 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.849ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84937 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.848ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84856 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.848ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84856 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84263 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.854ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.85395 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.843ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84371 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8429 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.843ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8429 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.861ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.86123 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.058ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.05848 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.881ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.88144 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.843ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84371 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84209 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.896ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.89653 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.842ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84236 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.843ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84398 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.886ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.88656 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.85ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85099 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.848ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.84883 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.066ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.06683 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.888ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.88817 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.853ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85341 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.056ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.05605 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.88ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8809 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.882ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.88224 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.849ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85018 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.243ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.24333 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.849ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85018 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.109ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.10914 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.006ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.00647 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.852ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.8526 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.534ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.53463 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 2.368ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   2.3681 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.853ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85368 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.843ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84371 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84533 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.852ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.85233 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.849ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8491 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84587 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.891ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.89168 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.846ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84587 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.846ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.8464 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84587 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.848ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.84829 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.846ms (steady)   15.6ms (hires)   1.84614 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.8456 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84506 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.872ms (steady)   15.6001ms (hires)   1.87281 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84452 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84587 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.844ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84425 (qpc)
Elapsed time: 1.845ms (steady)   0ms (hires)   1.84479 (qpc)

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.499 s
Press any key to continue
```

Notice how the high resolution clock fluctuates between 0 and 15.6ms and notice the steady_clock comparison.

The issue I have is that is that if I were to implement a fixed-time game loop where the update() code updates entity positions at exactly 1000/60 (60 update cycles a second) i.e. every 16.666etc ms - then this is very close to the returned hires timer fluctuating value! The real problem is that if I also implement an accumulator in order to accommodate both game loop frame times that are under 1000/60ms and any leftover once update() has completed, the update loop is entered sooner - and at irregular time points - than it should.

Is there an issue with the minimal code above, and if not, should I be concerned with this for any proper fixed-time implementation?
Additionally, and if relevant, is there any way to isolate a program/thread so that it is not interrupted by system IRQ or other polling events? I'm guessing the hires timer may be subject to such interruptions.

Comment: Usually you use a sleep, not a busy-wait

Comment: I've artificially constructed the minimal code to show the odd behaviour I'm experiencing with the high res timer. My actual game code (doesn't use a 'busy-wait') also exhibits this issue where the game cycles fluctuate between 0 and 15.6ms.......or more accurately (where the game loop is busier), there appears an issue with 15.6ms being irregularly added to the game loop.

Comment: I agree with Ben Voigt that your standard library's implementation of std::chrono is buggy.  Even with a low quality implementation, I don't see how your output is reasonable.  I see nothing wrong with your code.  Perhaps on this platform you need to define your own `chrono::clock`.  Here is an example of how to turn the rdtsc assembly instruction into a `chrono::clock`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5524138/576911

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a bug in your standard library's implementation of `std::chrono`.

I'm aware of one such bug in Visual C++, not sure what compiler you are using but if support for `std::chrono` is a recent addition they might still have some flaws.

If you are using Visual C++, you should be aware of:

- [C++  header's high_resolution_clock does not have high resolution](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/)
- [steady_clock class and clock() function are non conformant with C++11 and C11 standards](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753115/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm aware of the VS bug (used VS Express 2013 previously) and am now using CodeBlocks IDE with minGW-w64 (x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5) as the compiler. I understood (probably wrongly) that this compiler didn't have this problem.

Comment: @Jim: Does that use msvcrt.dll or newlib as the runtime library?  I thought mingw uses msvcrt .... which means it will inherit many Microsoft bugs.

Comment: I do see libmsvcrt.a at C:\Program Files\mingw-builds\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib. If this is the issue do you know of any other compiler that doesn't have this issue? It took a very long time in trying out various mingw versions before settle on this version (though I did learn a lot in the process).

Comment: So it is using the msvc runtime library.  I *think* that only affects the C Standard Library, and not C++ library (depending on how the C++ library is built on top of the C library and Win32 API -- they certainly had the option of building on QueryPerformanceCounter).  Still, I imagine that the mingw port of g++ and library gets much less testing than on Linux.

Comment: IIRC correctly, C++11 doesn't attempt to make any corrections to account for CPU frequency changes (or other events like a sleep/hibernate) with the `high_resolution_clock`, does it?  Isn't it effectively intended to sit on an instruction like `rtdsc` (x86/x64) that gets the tick count of the CPU?

Comment: RDTSC no longer varies with dynamic clock changes

Comment: If it makes any difference (and trying to remember my BIOS settings) CPU-Z shows my i7920 to be fairly well fixed at an overclocked 3800MHz, varying by around 0.20 MHz. I chose this rather than allow automatic frequency changes.

Comment: Thanks all for this. I'll try out Howard's suggestion. I realise others are available e.g. Boost, however, I'm keen to keep overheads down if possible.

Comment: @Jim: Howard's implementation is good for exposition for terrible for actual usage.  You don't want your CPU frequency fixed in your source code.  Try `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency` instead, which should be precise within less than 1 microsecond.

Comment: @Ben: Upon checking Howard's link out I thought the same thing (frequency tied) though as he rightly says 'useful for investigation purposes'.  For myself, back to Googling QueryPerformanceCounter and/or QueryPerformanceFrequency custom implementations; I might also check out Boost::chrono after all (hoping there's no issues of accuracy between 32bit / 64bit Windows).

Comment: I've edited the minimal code and output windows to include a possible implementation of the QueryPerformanceCounter to the mix. It seems to be in line with the steady clock, though at a higher resolution (as hoped). It's based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter. I'd be grateful if someone could answer if this (QPC) implementation would be robust/safe enough to use downstream (e.g. game loop timing).

Comment: @Jim: QPC is rock solid, it's good for almost any purpose.  That said, your new results are interesting... and I think you are not showing the full resolution of the `steady_clock`.  Could you try `duration_cast<microseconds>(...).count()/1000.0` instead?

Comment: In line with the above qpc link, to return the qpc as microseconds I've temporarily amended the code to "PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000000.0;" and displayed the output as a separate window.

Comment: It was steady_clock I wanted to see in microseconds.  I think you're rounding it unfairly right now.

Comment: Apologies, Ben, for the misread (a bit late last night). I've presented the new run data and altered window description to reflect the steady_clock conversion back to milli, this time from microseconds.

Comment: @Jim: Looks like you might be best off just using `steady_clock`, since it seems to have good precision as well.