# Why the runtime of filling my std::vector jumps between 0 and ~16ms?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, runtime

The bottleneck of my c++ application is filling an std::vector< std::vector< Chunk > >. Sometimes this takes 0ms and sometimes ~16ms, it takes never something between, like 2-14ms. Why? I fill allways about 5000 elements in the vector. My code is:

Chunk struct:

```
struct Chunk {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, int>>> chreatures_;
};
```

init:

```
int height_ = 100;
int width_ = 100;
const int chunksidelength_ = 10;
std::vector<std::vector<Chunk>> chunks_;
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Creature>> creatures_;

chunks_.reserve(height_ / chunksidelength_);
for (int i = 0; i < height_ / chunksidelength_; i++) {
    chunks_.emplace_back();
    chunks_[i].reserve(width_ / chunksidelength_);
    for (int j = 0; j < width_ / chunksidelength_; j++) {
        chunks_[i].emplace_back();
        chunks_[i][j].chreatures_.
                reserve(chunksidelength_ * chunksidelength_ * 3);
    }
}
```

filling:

```
long long before = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
    (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())).count();

for (std::vector<Chunk>& chunks : chunks_) {
    for (Chunk& chunk : chunks) {
        chunk.chreatures_.clear();
    }
}

for (const std::shared_ptr<Creature>& creature : creatures_) {
    int x = creature->x() / chunksidelength_;
    int y = creature->y() / chunksidelength_;
    std::string image = creature->image_path();
    std::pair<int, int> position(creature->x(), creature->y());
    chunks_[y][x].chreatures_.emplace_back(std::make_pair(image, position));
}

long long after = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
    (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())).count();
std::cout << after - before << std::endl;
```

Comment: My first guess would always be memory allocations and context switching associated with that. Try statically allocated vector (with your own allocator) and see how it changes things.

Comment: @SergeyA in the creatures_ vector of a Chunk an reallocation should never happen, because for every Chunk creautres_.capacity is bigger than the count of elements inserted. Is there another place where I could look for reallocations?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on this but could it possibly be some kind of register overflow or other memory type change (stack, registers, main memory etc). Maybe sometimes when you reach over a certain factor of a number of elements, you overflow enough to switch to another form of memory, or another clear and fill type operation pattern.

Comment: Could you try to run the same code on multiple different computers? Just to find out whether this happens only in your particular runtime environment.

Comment: @user3561614 Are you timing an optimized build?  That is important as to whether this issue is really worth pursuing.

Comment: You have the `std::string` part which may allocate. (and `std::string image = creature->image_path()` should probably be const ref, or then missing `std::move` for the `std::pair`).

Comment: I recommend you change your data structure to `std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, int> >`.  The `map` is a data structure optimized for accesses by key (speeding up the search).

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Windows? Is the timer resolution [15.6 ms](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/)? That may mean that your code just 'executes very quickly', in 0 or 1 timer ticks.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470315/odd-behaviour-using-chronohigh-resolution-clocknow

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. My time meassurement also returns values like 2-15 for other tasks, but perhaps after allocation of new memory for std::string it takes until the next timerinterrupt, that the OS gives the program processortime.