# Multi-platform equivalent to QueryPerformanceCounter?

Tags: performance, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

In Windows, I've used `QueryPerformanceCounter` to measure code performance in microseconds. I would like to do the same in all platforms within Firemonkey. I found [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879670/c-cross-platform-equivalent-of-windows-queryperformancecounter), but it's only for C++.

What's the equivalent for all platforms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`TStopwatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) from `System.Diagnostics`.

- On Windows it is implemented with `QueryPerformanceCounter`.
- On Mac OS it is implemented with `mach_absolute_time`.
- On POSIX platforms it is implemented with `clock_gettime`.