# Does C++ have built-in timers?

Tags: c++, timer

I have to use timer in C++ to avoid using `sleep()` function. I have to do something at specified interval. I don't want to use `WinApi` timer class, because I want it work on both Linux and Windows.

Does C++ have built-in timer classes?

Comment: You might use the periodic function reviewed here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47347/follow-up-timer-utilizing-stdfuture

Comment: Look at headers `<chrono>`, `<ctime>` and `<time.h>`.

Comment: Are you looking for "cross platform timer"? Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer

Comment: Well, nowadays you could do exactly what you are currently doing in a portable and standard way: Open a thread for the timer with `<thread>`, and sleep it by some intervals with `<chrono>`

Comment: @Manu343726 I'm not sure just moving the sleep() call to a different thread counts as avoiding the use of sleep()  ;)