# C++ Getting more precise tickcount values

Tags: c++

I am timing the performance of some operations in c++ using Tick Count:

```
DWORD tstart = GetTickCount();                  
{                                           
    //...Some Operation...
}                                           
DWORD tend = GetTickCount();                        
double tt = (double) (tend-tstart)/(double) 1000;   
std::cout << "Exec Time: " << tt << " Seconds" << std::endl;
```

However, this only gives me value >= 0.015...

Any value below 0.015 seems to be printed as simply 0..

Is there any other way to get more precision?

Comment: C++ has `<chrono>`, which has a high-resolution clock. AFAIK, a really recent VS update fixed the clocks, too.

Comment: btw, `(double) 1000` can be written as `1000.` (or `1000.0` if you want). Any [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487695/c-cross-platform-high-resolution-timer) can help.

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter in Windows API is a good choice if your code is supposed to be compiled and run on Windows only.

Comment: Seems C11 has `timespec` if a standard C solution is desired.

Comment: Found [the change](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/06/c-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) I was talking about. It's a fix in VS14 CTP 1: *We've fixed this by making high_resolution_clock a typedef for steady_clock (as permitted by the Standard), which is now powered by QueryPerformanceCounter(), which is high resolution and meets the Standard's requirements for steadiness/monotonicity.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` for highest resolution

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
auto start = Clock::now();
... do some work ...
auto stop = Clock::now();

std::cout << stop-start << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cout formatters.

```
include <iomanip>

std::cout << "Exec Time: " << std::setprecision(12) << tt << " Seconds" << std::endl;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

I recommend also use of **chrono** new in C++11.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point begin_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

... work ...

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
long long elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end_time-begin_time).count();
std::cout << "Duration (min:seg): " << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (elapsed_seconds / 60) << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (elapsed_seconds % 60) << std::endl;
```

Comment: `GetTickCount` has a low precision.